# Compile time sizeof_array without using a macro

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, puzzle

This is just something that has bothered me for the last couple of days, I don't think it's possible to solve but I've seen template magic before.

Here goes:

To get the number of elements in a standard C++ array I could use either a macro (1), or a typesafe inline function (2):

**(1)**

```
#define sizeof_array(ARRAY) (sizeof(ARRAY)/sizeof(ARRAY[0]))
```

**(2)**

```
template <typename T>
size_t sizeof_array(const T& ARRAY){
    return (sizeof(ARRAY)/sizeof(ARRAY[0]));
}
```

As you can see, the first one has the problem of being a macro (for the moment I consider that a problem) and the other one has the problem of not being able to get the size of an array at compile time; ie I can't write:

```
enum ENUM{N=sizeof_array(ARRAY)};
```

or

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof_array(ARRAY)==10);// Assuming the size 10..
```

Does anyone know if this can be solved?

***Update***:

This question was created before constexpr was introduced. Nowadays you can simply use:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto sizeof_array(const T& iarray) {
    return (sizeof(iarray) / sizeof(iarray[0]));
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95500/can-this-macro-be-converted-to-a-function

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try the following from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
char ( &_ArraySizeHelper( T (&array)[N] ))[N];
#define mycountof( array ) (sizeof( _ArraySizeHelper( array ) ))

int testarray[10];
enum { testsize = mycountof(testarray) };

void test() {
    printf("The array count is: %d\n", testsize);
}
```

It should print out: "The array count is: 10"

Comment: Note -- for your two issues:

#1) Macros : you do not have to use the countof() macro, you can just use sizeof(_ArraySizeHelper( array )) but the countof() macro is a simplification.

#2) enums -- it works with enums in the above example

Comment: +1.  This has the added benefit of being typesafe (i.e., it will fail to compile if you pass a pointer instead of an array).

Comment: Its a nice solution, but not completely general: "it doesn’t work with types defined inside a function"

Comment: @gf: Templates in general don't work so well for types defined inside a function.  In fact, it doesn't work for STL -- the following won't compile under GCC: void test() { struct foo{ int a; }; std::vector<foo> b; }  You're much better off using a namespace (or anonymous namespace) if you need to create a class that is only going to be used by one function and you need to use templates on that class.

Comment: @Adisak, @Georg: I think there is a way to get this to work for local types: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500363/compile-time-sizeof-array-without-using-a-macro/6256085#6256085

Answer (score 19):

In C++1x `constexpr` will get you that:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t countof(T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: The same can be written in C++99, and in most cases the compiler will optimize away the call.

Comment: But in C++98 it can't be used where a constant expression is expected

Comment: Yep... won't work on an enum -- at least on any of my pre-C++1X current C++ compilers that I actually have to use for work.

Answer (score 8):

The best I can think of is this:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
char (&sizeof_array(T (&a)[N]))[N];

// As litb noted in comments, you need this overload to handle array rvalues
// correctly (e.g. when array is a member of a struct returned from function),
// since they won't bind to non-const reference in the overload above.
template <class T, std::size_t N>
char (&sizeof_array(const T (&a)[N]))[N];
```

which has to be used with another `sizeof`:

```
int main()
{
    int a[10];
    int n = sizeof(sizeof_array(a));
    std::cout << n << std::endl;
}
```

**[EDIT]**

Come to think of it, I believe this is provably impossible to do in a single "function-like call" in C++03, apart from macros, and here's why.

On one hand, you will clearly need template parameter deduction to obtain size of array (either directly, or via `sizeof` as you do). However, template parameter deduction is only applicable to functions, and not to classes; i.e. you can have a template parameter R of type reference-to-array-of-N, where N is another template parameter, but you'll have to provide both R and N at the point of the call; if you want to deduce N from R, only a function call can do that.

On the other hand, the only way any expression involving a function call can be constant is when it's inside `sizeof`. Anything else (e.g. accessing a static or enum member on return value of function) still requires the function call to occur, which obviously means this won't be a constant expression.

Comment: Remove the `const` to make it more generic.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It will be able to deduce `T` as `const U` if it gets a `const U[N]&` as an argument, right?

Comment: I like to use identity in these case, because it greatly improves readability: `template<typename T, size_t N> typename identity<char[N]>::type &sizeof_array(T const(&)[N]);` . For the `const` removal - this actually decreased genericity. Because now you cannot accept rvalue arrays anymore (non-const array reference won't bind to rvalue arrays): `struct A { int b[2]; }; .. sizeof_array(A().b); // doesn't work if it's not const!`. Notice that this rvalue array is not const itself, so deduction won't put const either. Note that this isn't a big issue - but arguably it's less generic i think.

Comment: The rvalue array isn't `const` itself, but its element type is `const`, so why wouldn't it be deduced? As a side note, both MSVC and (more reassuringly) Comeau are able to deduce `T` as `const int` when passing `const int a[10]` just fine.

Comment: If the element type of an array is const, the array is const too, it propagates up (given `typedef int a[10];`, then `a const` is the same type as `int const[10]`) . In any case, surely with `int const a[10]; sizeof_array(a);` it works. But `a` is an lvalue, and its type is `int const[a]`, so `T` is `int const`. In case of `struct A { int b[2]; }; ... sizeof_array(getAnA().b);` the passed array is an rvalue, and its type is `int[2]`, so `T` is `int` - but non-const references won't bind to rvalues. Surely rvalue arrays are seldom, but nonetheless, genericity decreased instead of increased :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right regarding rvalue arrays... looks like this really needs two overloads to be fully generic. I'll add that.

Comment: Note that it's fine for the `T const(&)[N]` to accept non-const arrays. Deduction will deduce `T` normally and will not get distracted by the additional const. It promotes use of `const` instead - wouldn't be good if deduction would force people to omit `const` if they want to accept non-const arguments. :) Anyway, upvoted you because of your nice analysis and sane naming (no insane underscores in front of names etc xD).

Answer (score 6):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but it's close - a snippet from `winnt.h` which includes some explanation of what the #$%^ it's doing:

```
//
// RtlpNumberOf is a function that takes a reference to an array of N Ts.
//
// typedef T array_of_T[N];
// typedef array_of_T &reference_to_array_of_T;
//
// RtlpNumberOf returns a pointer to an array of N chars.
// We could return a reference instead of a pointer but older compilers do not accept that.
//
// typedef char array_of_char[N];
// typedef array_of_char *pointer_to_array_of_char;
//
// sizeof(array_of_char) == N
// sizeof(*pointer_to_array_of_char) == N
//
// pointer_to_array_of_char RtlpNumberOf(reference_to_array_of_T);
//
// We never even call RtlpNumberOf, we just take the size of dereferencing its return type.
// We do not even implement RtlpNumberOf, we just decare it.
//
// Attempts to pass pointers instead of arrays to this macro result in compile time errors.
// That is the point.
//
extern "C++" // templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (*RtlpNumberOf( UNALIGNED T (&)[N] ))[N];

#define RTL_NUMBER_OF_V2(A) (sizeof(*RtlpNumberOf(A)))
```

The `RTL_NUMBER_OF_V2()` macro ends up being used in the more readable `ARRAYSIZE()` macro.

[Matthew Wilson's "Imperfect C++"](http://www.synesis.com.au/publishing/imperfect/cpp/) book also has a discussion of the techniques that are used here.

Comment: +1 : Reading the countOf code had me puzzled (I try not to spend much time mastering the obscure declaration rules C++ inherited from C). This answer provides with the exact info on what is exactly RtlpNumberOf.

Answer (score 6):

### The Problem

I like [Adisak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500363/compile-time-sizeof-array-without-using-a-macro/1500517#1500517):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
char ( &_ArraySizeHelper( T (&arr)[N] ))[N];
#define COUNTOF( arr ) (sizeof( _ArraySizeHelper( arr ) ))
```

It's what Microsoft uses for the [_countof macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) in VS2008, and it's got some nice features:

- It operates at **compile time**
- It's **typesafe** (i.e. it will generate a compile-time error if you give it a pointer, which arrays degrade too all too easily)

But as pointed out by [Georg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/168225/georg-fritzsche), this approach uses templates, so it's [not guaranteed to work with local types for C++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742607/using-local-classes-with-stl-algorithms):

```
void i_am_a_banana() {
  struct { int i; } arr[10];
  std::cout << COUNTOF(arr) << std::endl; // forbidden in C++03
}
```

Fortunately, we're not out luck.

### The Solution

Ivan Johnson came up with [a clever approach](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/197800525?pgno=1) that wins on all accounts: it's typesafe, compile-time, and works with local types:

```
#define COUNTOF(arr) ( \
   0 * sizeof(reinterpret_cast<const ::Bad_arg_to_COUNTOF*>(arr)) + \
   0 * sizeof(::Bad_arg_to_COUNTOF::check_type((arr), &(arr))) + \
   sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]) )

struct Bad_arg_to_COUNTOF {
   class Is_pointer; // incomplete
   class Is_array {};
   template <typename T>
   static Is_pointer check_type(const T*, const T* const*);
   static Is_array check_type(const void*, const void*);
};
```

For those who are interested, it works by inserting two "tests" before the standard sizeof-based array-size macro.  Those tests don't impact the final calculation, but are designed to generate compile errors for non-array types:

1. The first test fails unless `arr` is integral, enum, pointer, or array.  `reinterpret_cast<const T*>` should fail for any other types.
2. The second test fails for integral, enum, or pointer types.

   Integral and enum types will fail because there's no version of `check_type` that they match, since `check_type` expects pointers.

   Pointer types will fail because they'll match the templated version of `check_type`, but the return type (`Is_pointer`) for the templated `check_type` is incomplete, which will produce an error.

   Array types will pass because taking the address of an array of type `T`
   will give you `T (*)[]`, aka a pointer-to-an-array, not a pointer-to-a-pointer. That means that the templated version of `check_type` won't match. Thanks to [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), the compiler will move on to the non-templated version of `check_type`, which should accept any pair of pointers.  Since the return type for the non-templated version is defined completely, no error will be produced.  And since we're not dealing with templates now, local types work fine.

Comment: It is no template implementation, but the best I've found so far.

Comment: I like Ivan Johnson's idea, but I'm a bit confused.  In C++11 there are simpler solutions, so let's assume that we don't have that.  Then templates won't pick up local classes, so won't `localClass x; std::size_t length = COUNTOF(&x);` actually compile?  (Sorry, I don't have a compiler that implements that old "feature" handy.)

Comment: I may have been mistaken.  Calling `COUNTOF(&x)` might lead to an _attempt_ to instantiate the `Is_pointer check_type` with `localClass` as the `template` parameter, perhaps causing a compile-time error (rather than just SFINAE).  I can't tell if this was previously guaranteed by the standard or just unclear and assumed.

Comment: I tested this on `g++`. In C++11 mode everything seemed to work correctly, but in non-C++11 mode `g++` was "happy" to compile `LocalType x; LocalType *ptr = &x; std::size_t length = COUNTOF(ptr);` with `length` getting, of course, a completely meaningless value. Whether this is an "extension," a valid interpretation of an ambiguous standard, or a bug is unclear to me, but regardless it seems that a completely type-safe version that handles local types is out of reach pre-C++11.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on a Microsoft only platform, you can take advantage of the [_countof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(VS.80).aspx) macro.  This is a non-standard extension which will return the count of elements within an array.  It's advantage over most countof style macros is that it will cause a compilation error if it's used on a non-array type.

The following works just fine (VS 2008 RTM)

```
static int ARRAY[5];
enum ENUM{N=_countof(ARRAY)};
```

But once again, it's MS specific so this may not work for you.

Comment: _countof is implemented as a macro for C and a typesafe inline function for C++; in other words, it's identical to the question's (1) and (2).

Answer (score 3):

You can't solve it in general, thats one the reasons for array wrappers like [boost array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost/array.html) (plus stl-style behaviour of course).

Comment: -1: Wrong. Template metaprogramming can solve it, even before C++11.

Comment: @ThomasEding: Expand on how you would solve the two specific examples in the question without macros pre-C++11. The question originally was about how to solve them without doing macros.

Comment: Observe Nate Kohls answer for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/6256085/239916. (He uses a macro, but that's just a convenience; it's not necessary.) I haven't tried, but I believe it should be possible and fairly straightforward to emulate `decltype` in C++03, thus you could write the equivalent of C++11's `std::extent<std::enable_if<std::is_array<decltype(x)>::value, decltype(x)>::type>::value` in C++03. Yes, those traits don't exist natively in C++03, but those are definitely implementable.

Comment: That answer is interesting if it works properly with local types, but without macros that's effectively unusable (as in, you won't use it in practice). Emulating `decltype` in C++03 is not feasible. Also, reducing expressions like the above in C++03 to usable length/syntax sounds unrealistic.

Comment: @George: You're right. I thought certain things were possible to do in C++ (even in C++11) that are not possible to do at all when I tried writing some code for it. I can't remove my downvote apparently... wow.

Comment: Right, your votes get locked until the next edit, it's fine (i was more concerned about what i may have missed).

Answer (score 2):

It appears not to be possible to obtain the sizeof array as a compile-time constant without a macro with current C++ standard (you need a function to deduce the array size, but function calls are not allowed where you need a compile-time constant). [Edit: But see Minaev's brilliant solution!]

However, your template version isn't typesafe either and suffers from the same problem as the macro: it also accepts pointers and notably arrays decayed to a pointer. When it accepts a pointer, the result of sizeof(T*) / sizeof(T) cannot be meaningful.

Better:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t sizeof_array(T (&)[N]){
    return N;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without C++0x, the closest I can get is:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct count_of_type
{
};


template <typename T, unsigned N>
struct count_of_type<T[N]> 
{
    enum { value = N };
};

template <typename T, unsigned N>
unsigned count_of ( const T (&) [N] )
{
    return N;
};


int main ()
{
    std::cout << count_of_type<int[20]>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << count_of_type<char[42]>::value << std::endl;

    // std::cout << count_of_type<char*>::value << std::endl; // compile error

    int foo[1234];

    std::cout << count_of(foo) << std::endl;

    const char* bar = "wibble";

    // std::cout << count_of( bar ) << std::endl; // compile error

    enum E1 { N = count_of_type<int[1234]>::value } ;

    return 0;
}
```

which either gives you a function you can pass the variable to, or a template you can pass the type too. You can't use the function for a compile time constant, but most cases you know the type, even if only as template parameter.

Comment: With C++0x, you _can_ use a function for a compile time constant, if you declare it `constexpr` - as other answers have pointed out.

Comment: Having read that post I put "Without C++0x" at the start of mine to show that I wasn't using that technique, but one which will work with current compilers.

Comment: The compile-time constant version looks a bit pointless, though. Why would you ever go through the trouble of typing count_of_type<int[20]>::value if you have to know the size is 20? :)

Comment: You might want count_of_type<T>::value where T is a template parameter, but I agree it's liable to be rare.

Answer (score 2):

Now STL libraries are available to decide/select array size compile time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<class T>
void test(T t)
{
    int a[std::tuple_size<T>::value]; // can be used at compile time
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<T>::value << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::array<float, 3> arr;
    test(arr);
}
```

Output:
    3

Comment: You are way too low. Btw, now = c++11 and more