# How does this "size of array" template function work?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size, sizeof

Can someone explain how this code works? I know that the purpose of this code is to get the length of an array, but I don't know how this code works:

```
template<typename T, int size>
int GetArrLength(T(&)[size]){return size;}
```

Comment: @thyrgle: this has the advantage over `sizeof` that, if you accidentally give it a pointer instead of an array, it will fail to compile.

Comment: @litb: There's no incentive to find duplicates, apart from 'getting generally annoyed'. It often takes longer to search for a duplicate and vote for a close than it does to re-answer a question and you tend to get more reputation for re-answering the question than you do for closing as duplicate _even if you have the top answer to the question that the new question is a duplicate of_. Sigh.

Comment: duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384107/magic-arguments-in-function-templates and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array

Answer (score 79):

First let's dissect the parameter, `T(&)[size]`. Read declarations from inside out, right to left, parenthesis group first: It's an unnamed parameter that is a reference to an array of size `size` of type `T`.

That is, it accepts a reference to any array, where the type and size of the array are template parameters.

If we call it as such:

```
int a[10];
GetArrLength(a);
```

The compiler will try to deduce the template parameters. For the parameter type to match what you're passing, `T` must be `int` and `size` must be 10 (making the parameter a reference to an array of 10 `int`s).

You then return that size, giving you the number of elements in an array.

---

There are two "problems" with this code. Firstly, sizes cannot be negative, so it doesn't make sense to use a signed type as the template parameter and return type. Rather, an unsigned type should be used; best would be `std::size_t`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
std::size_t GetArrLength(T(&)[Size]) { return size; }
```

The second is that the result of this function is not a constant-expression, even though an array's size is. While that's fine in most situations, it would be better if we could get a constant-expression from it. That's where you end up with this solution:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct type_of_size
{
    typedef char type[N];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
typename type_of_size<Size>::type& sizeof_array_helper(T(&)[Size]);

#define sizeof_array(pArray) sizeof(sizeof_array_helper(pArray))
```

This is used as such:

```
int a[10];
const std::size_t n = sizeof_array(a); // constant-expression!
```

It works by three things: the first is the same idea as above, that template parameters will be filled out giving you the array's size.

The second part is using that information to make a type with a specific size, hence the `type_of_size` helper. That part isn't strictly necessary, but I think it makes the code easier to read. A `char[N]` has a size equal to `N`, always, hence we can abuse that to "store" the size of the array...in the size of a *type* itself!

The third part is getting that size with `sizeof`. It doesn't actually evaluate anything, so we don't need a definition for the function. It simply says "If you were to do this...the size would be...". And the size is our "stored" size, in the `char` array.

Comment: but if I change the code into 
T&[size]

it won't work, why?

what is the difference between (&) and only &

thanks

Comment: T&[size] is an array of references.  You want a reference to an array.

Comment: @Bob: It has to do with declarations. You might be getting confused because there is no name for it, try sticking one in there. With `T(&x)[N]` x is reference to an array of N T's. But with: `T&x[N]` x is an array of N references to T. (Which is illegal.) Read declarations from inside-out, right-to-left, parenthesis first.

Comment: You can skip boiler plate code in the last version at the cost of readability, but I am writting this as an exercise for @Matthew Flaschen and @BobAlmond :) `template <typename T, size_t size> char (&sizeof_array_helper( T (&)[size]))[size];` -- the macro would be left as it is.

Comment: With C++11's `constexpr`, the 'return n;' function becomes a compile time constant! `template <typename T, size_t n> constexpr size_t array_size(const T (&)[n]) { return n; }`

Comment: Since the example ended up with a macro anyway, why is it any better than the simplest `#define sizeof_array(arr) (sizeof arr / sizeof *arr)` ?

Comment: @user666412: Yours is not type safe: `int* i = ...; sizeof_array(i) /* should not compile */`

Comment: that's a good point.

Comment: #define sizeof_array(array) \
  (sizeof(type_of_size(array)))

template <typename T, size_t N>
auto type_of_size(const T (&array)[N]) -> char (&)[N];

Comment: With C++11 constexpr functions, we can just return Size.
`template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t GetArrLength(T(&)[Size]) { return Size; }`
However this will not work if you call it on a static array from a class member function where the array is also a member of the same class. This causes an implicit use of the this ptr that is not allowed by the standard.

Comment: This short snippet requires knowing many CPP concepts: non-type template parameters, type traits, and dependent names. Also, the fact that the function `sizeof_array_helper` doesn't need to be defined could be puzzling.