# Is there a guarantee as to the size of a class that contains an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, metaprogramming, sizeof

Given:

```
template <int N>
struct val2size
{
    char placeholder[N];
};
```

Is there any guarantee that `sizeof(val2size<N>) == N`?

Comment: You can get the same thing from `boost::array<char,N>` or C++0x `std::array`.

Comment: Note that most of the answers assumed you were speaking of ONLY containing an array, and no other members. The more members there are, the more likely it is that the size of the object is superior to the sum of their individual sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only guarantee is that

```
sizeof(val2size<N>) >= N
```

There *may* be unnamed padding at the end of the struct.  I don't think it's likely that there will be unnamed padding, but it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, so I suspected. Assuming that on practically any platform `sizeof(int)` is the natural word size (not sure if it's defined to be that way, though) is there a chance for padding in case it was an int array (with the size then being `N * sizeof(int)`)?

Comment: @uj2: From the AMD64 ABI http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf "An array uses the same alignment as its elements, except that a local or global array variable of length at least 16 bytes or a C99 variable-length array variable always has alignment of at least 16 bytes." It sounds like an array *subobject* will be exempt from this, but it's easy enough to try and see.

Comment: More generally speaking, it's somewhat reasonable for another ABI including vector types to extend such a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

No, [James covers that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647562/is-there-a-guarantee-as-to-the-size-of-a-class-that-contains-an-array/3647567#3647567). But you can get what you want with:

```
template <std::size_t N> // not an int, a negative value doesn't make sense
struct value_to_size
{
    typedef char type[N];
};
```

`sizeof(value_to_size<N>::type)` is guaranteed to be `N`. (This trick can be used to make a [compile-time size-of array utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368883/how-does-this-size-of-array-template-function-work/3368894#3368894).)

Comment: @uj2: Nothing in your question says anything about a return type. Why not ask a real question about a real problem, rather than a step?

Comment: @uj2: Nothing stops you from using `val2size` as a _return type_. But what are you trying to achieve by equating a type to a particular value? Compile time checks?

Comment: You're correct. It is a partial question, although I felt it deserved to be asked separatly. The comment probablly wasn't too helpful though, it's a valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there is no guarantee because of possible padding. However, many compilers (at least VC++ and gcc) allow you to set the alignment of structures using a pragma, like this:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
template <int N>
struct val2size
{
    char placeholder[N];
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Setting the alignment to 1 essentially prevents any additional padding at the end of the structure.

Comment: _Valid values are 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16. The alignment of a member will be on a boundary that is either a multiple of n or a multiple of the size of the member, whichever is smaller._ From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I actually meant 1. It's been a while since I used it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of N actually and whether that size of N char can be fit in a world align manner. If the memory of character array is world align ( 4 byte align for 32 bit and 8 byte align for 64 bit) then you will get sizeof==N or if not then it will add padding to make the memory allocated to be world align and in that case it will be >=N.