# Can you use the result of an array size function as an array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size, c++98

```
// sizeofarray.cpp
#include <iostream>
template <typename T,int N>
int size(T (&Array)[N])
{
  return N;
}

int main()
{
   char p[]="Je suis trop bon, et vous?";
   char q[size(p)]; // (A)
   return 0;
}
```

I heard that an array size in C++ must be a constant expression. So `char q[size(p)]` is invalid, am I right? But I got no errors when I tried

```
 g++ -Wall sizeofarray.cpp
```

Why?

Comment: `q[sizeof(p)]` is fine, you probably meant `q[size(p)]`. Note that the latter will become valid in C++0x (if you declare `size` as `constexpr`).

Comment: The issue is with the 'size' instead of sizeof. See my post.

Comment: Try the compiler options -pedantic or -std=c++98  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

> I heard that an array size in C++ must be a constant expression.

Correct

> So char q[size(p)] is invalid, am I right?

According to ISO C++, yes!

> But I got no errors when I tried
>
> g++ -Wall sizeofarray.cpp

That's because g++ supports VLA ([Variable Length Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)) as an extension.

In `C++0x` there is [`constexpr`](http://www2.research.att.com/%7Ebs/C++0xFAQ.html#constexpr) feature with the help of which you can write

```
constexpr int size(T (&Array)[N])
{
  return N;
}
```

and then `char q[size(p)]` would be legal.

**EDIT** : Also read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx) article [blog whatever]

Comment: surely sizeof is a constant expression(atleast for a non-vla which standard C++ doesn't even have) ?

Answer (score 4):

Like [Prasoon says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831158/using-size-of-one-array-in-another-array/3831176#3831176), it's not a constant expression. For now, you can get a constant-expression value of the size of an array like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct type_of_size
{
    typedef char type[N];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
typename type_of_size<Size>::type& sizeof_array_helper(T(&)[Size]);

#define sizeof_array(pArray) sizeof(sizeof_array_helper(pArray))
```

Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368883/how-does-this-size-of-array-template-function-work-closed). You basically encode the size of the array into the size of a type, then get the `sizeof` of that type, giving you:

```
char q[sizeof_array(p)];
```

Answer (score -1):

I beg to differ with all the answers here. The code show is perfectly fine except for a  minor issue (which is definitely not VLA)

```
template <typename T,int N> 
int size(T (&Array)[N]) 
{ 
  return N; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
   char p[]="Je suis trop bon, et vous?"; 
   char q[sizeof(p)]; // (A), not sizeof and not size as in OP
   return 0; 
}
```

I was wondering that the result of the sizeof is always a const value, and hence the code should be fine.

The above code builds fine on VS 2010 and Comeau(strict mode)

> $5.3.3/6- "The result is a constant of
>   type size_t. [Note: size_t is defined
>   in the standard header (18.1)."

Comment: I think he probably meant `char q[size(p)]`. I have made the necessary corrections in the OP.

Answer (score -1):

I use g++ 4.4.3 and have the following alias so that I never forget to turn on the warnings:

```
$ alias g++
alias g++='g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -W -Wconversion -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings'
```

**If compiled with the above, there would be some warnings.** Following steps show how different options show different warnings.

Compilation with no warning option does not show any warning

```
$ \g++ sizeofarray.cpp
```

Turning on `-Wall`

```
$ \g++ -Wall sizeofarray.cpp
sizeofarray.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sizeofarray.cpp:12: warning: unused variable ‘q’
```

Turning on `-Wextra`

```
$ \g++ -Wall -Wextra sizeofarray.cpp 
sizeofarray.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sizeofarray.cpp:12: warning: unused variable ‘q’
sizeofarray.cpp: At global scope:
sizeofarray.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int size(T (&)[N]) [with T = char, int N = 27]’:
sizeofarray.cpp:12:   instantiated from here
sizeofarray.cpp:4: warning: unused parameter ‘Array’
```

Finally turning on `-pedantic` to catch the real problem

```
$ \g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  sizeofarray.cpp 
sizeofarray.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
sizeofarray.cpp:12: warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘q’
sizeofarray.cpp:12: warning: unused variable ‘q’
sizeofarray.cpp: At global scope:
sizeofarray.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int size(T (&)[N]) [with T = char, int N = 27]’:
sizeofarray.cpp:12:   instantiated from here
sizeofarray.cpp:4: warning: unused parameter ‘Array’
```