# Why do sizeof statsements produce different results?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating size of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720077/calculating-size-of-an-array)
>   [Sizeof an array in the C programming language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/sizeof-an-array-in-the-c-programming-language)

Why does `sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])` work and `sizeof(arr+0)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])` not work?

And why does `sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])` also not work when arr is passed to a function? Here is the full code example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int givesize(int arr[])
{
   cout<<sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   cout<<sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])<<"\n";
   cout<<sizeof(arr+2)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])<<"\n";
   givesize(arr);
   return 0;
}
```

Output
5
1
1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720077/calculating-size-of-an-array, and hundreds of others

Answer (score 4):

This happens because [arrays decay to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/335858) when they are passed to functions that take pointers as arguments.

Inside your `main`, the

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

declaration is equivalent to

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

because the compiler has enough information to calculate the `5` from the aggregate initializer. In the function header, however, `int arr[]` does not mean the same thing: there is no context around it to tell the compiler that it's anything but a pointer to an integer.

Comment: Also the same thing happens with `arr+2`.

Comment: Not just any functions, only functions that take pointers.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley That's an excellent point, thank you very much!

Comment: To the OP: And then just in case you get confused by why the same doesn't apply to sizeof (like I was earlier this week) this one might be useful later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283361/why-does-decay-to-pointer-for-array-argument-appear-not-to-apply-to-sizeof

Answer (score 2):

`int arr[]` in a function argument list is the same as `int* arr`. Which means that in:

```
int givesize(int arr[])
{
   cout<<sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])<<"\n";
}
```

`sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])` is actually `sizeof(int*) / (double)sizeof(int)`. As it outputs `1` that implies a 32-bit platform.

`int arr[]` as a local variable is not the same as `int* arr`, hence `sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])` is the same as `sizeof(int[5]) / (double)sizeof(int)` which evaluates to 5.

Next, `sizeof(arr+2)/(double)sizeof(arr[0])` is again the same as `sizeof(int*) / (double)sizeof(int)`, because the type of expression `arr+2` is `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside main, arr has type "array of five ints", but arr+0 has type "pointer to int".  When you add zero to arr, you are treating it like a pointer, and as soon as you use an array like a pointer, it gets converted to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0]) work

Because `sizeof(arr)` returns the size of the entire array in bytes (let's say 20 assuming `int` is 32 bits), and `sizeof(arr[0])` returns the size of the first int (which is 4 bytes). This will give us 5.

> And why does sizeof(arr)/(double)sizeof(arr[0]) also not work when arr is passed to a function?

Because arrays decay into pointers. This means they lose an important piece of information: their size. We cannot directly calculate the size of an array just by a pointer. How would the function even know it is an array to begin with?

---

C++? Use a template function:

```
template <typename T, int N>
int getsize(const T (&arr)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```