# Size of a pointer to a 2d array?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a[5][5]={{2,4,6,8,10},{12,14,16,18,20}};
    cout <<sizeof(*(a))<<endl;
    cout <<sizeof(*(a+0))<<endl;
}
```

I am confused as to why the sizeof the pointer to a is 20. I thought *a gives you the address of a[0][0]. Is this giving us the size of the actual pointer or the size of the address the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: 2D arrays are actually arrays of arrays. `*a` gives you the first element of `a`, which is `a[0]` - an array of 5 integers. So, `sizeof(int) * 5` is 20.

Comment: @AdrianMole answers should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: If you're thinking that you'll get array-to-pointer decay, then that doesn't apply to the arguments of the `sizeof` operator. [Why does decay to pointer for array argument appear not to apply to sizeof()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11283361/10871073)

Comment: @MarkRansom I suspected a duplicate, so went looking ...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a short explanation of what I suspect your underlying confusion is: Arrays *decaying* to pointers does not mean that they **are** pointers.

Comment: So what exactly does `cout << a;` return? If `cout << &(a[0][0]) <<endl;` and `cout << a <<endl;` return the same thing then why is `*a` 20? Does that mean that `a` itself stores all the memory for all 5 integers but only prints the address of the first one?

Comment: "why the sizeof the pointer to a is 20" --> `*(a)` is not a _pointer_ to `a`.

Comment: @BintEuler   `cout << &(a[0][0]) <<endl;` takes `&a[0][0]`  (an `int *`), converts it to `void *`, and prints that.   `cout << a` prints `&a[0]` (an `int (*)[5]`), converts it to `void *`, and prints that.    The wrinkle is that `&a[0][0]` and `&a[0]` have different types (e.g. the expression `&a[0][0] == &a[0]` is a diagnosable error, due to a type mismatch, as no pointer decay occurs here) but they have the same value when converted to `void *` (that value, ignoring the type, is equal to the address in memory of the start of `a` in both cases)

Answer (score 2):

> I am confused as to why the sizeof the pointer to a is 20.

The size of a pointer to a is typically not 20.

> I thought *a gives you the address of a[0][0]

It does not. The unary `*` is the indirection operator. When you indirect through a pointer, you get the pointed value. It's the opposite operation of getting an address.

Now, `a` is not a pointer. It is an array. But an array can implicitly convert to a pointer to the first element. So, `a` which is an array of 5 arrays of 5 ints implicitly converts to a pointer to an array of 5 ints. When you indirect through that pointer, the result is an lvalue to an array of 5 ints that is the first element of `a`.

You are printing the size of an array of 5 ints. That happens to be 20 on your system.

> Does that mean that a itself stores all the memory for all 5 integers ...

An array stores all of its elements within itself. `a` stores all the memory of all 5 arrays, and each of the arrays contains the memory of all 5 integers each (25 in total).

> but [`cout << a;`] only prints the address of the first one?

There are no stream insertion operator overloads for arrays. But, there is a stream insertion operator overload for `void*`, and array can implicitly convert to a pointer to first element which can implicitly convert to `void*`. So, you are printing the address of the first element of the array.