# How to get the length of an array in c++?

Tags: c++

I tried to write my own function for this, but I get wrong result

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
int array_length(T v[]) {
    return (sizeof v)/sizeof(T);
}

int main() {
    int v[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    cout << array_length(v) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/3959946 see last function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368883/how-does-this-size-of-array-template-function-work

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: That function will give the size at runtime even though the compiler knows size at compile-time itself. Therefore, I wouldn't say that is a good implementation.

Comment: He only wants the array length at runtime.

Comment: The answers so far posted here only work for arrays whose size is known at compile time. AFAIK there is no portable way to find out the length of a dynamically allocated array (safe for remembering it yourself).

Comment: Is this the proper time to recommend `std::vector`, which knows its own size?

Comment: @BoPersson That's a good recommendation. Since OP is dealing with fixed size arrays, maybe `std::array` or `std::tr1::array` might be a better fit.

Comment: @DeadMG He didn't say that anywhere and giving a compile-time solution is always better than a runtime solution for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <cstddef> // for size_t

template< typename T, std::size_t N >
std::size_t length( const T (&)[N] )
{
  return N;
}
```

Usage

```
int data[100];
std::cout << length(data) << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible without includes (only iostream)?

Comment: @HardRain well, you could make it return an `unsigned long long` instead of a `std::size_t` for example.

Answer (score 1):

The length is supplied by the array. So try this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N> std::size_t length( T (&)[N] ) {
    return N;
}
```

<sub>[`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is found in header `<cstddef>`. It is an unsigned integer type.</sub>