# Finding number of prime numbers in an array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that finds the number of prime numbers in an array.

```
int countPrimes(int a[], int size)
{
    int numberPrime = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 2; j < a[i]; j++)
    {
        if(a[i] % j == 0)
            numbPrime++;
    }
    return numPrime;
}
```

I think what I'm missing is I have to redefine i after every iteration, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: For one thing, `numberPrime`, `numbPrime` and `numPrime` are not the same variable.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect - you will find all numbers that are divisible by some number 0 ... a[i] - that is not prime numbers... And yes, you need a for-loop outside the `for( j = ... )` loop.

Answer (score 5):

You need 2 loops: 1 over the array, 1 checking all possible divisors. I'd suggest separating out the prime check into a function. Code:

```
bool primeCheck(int p) {
    if (p<2) return false;

    // Really slow way to check, but works
    for(int d = 2; d<p; ++d) {
        if (0==p%d) return false; // found a divisor
    }
    return true; // no divisors found
}

int countPrimes(const int *a, int size) {
    int numberPrime = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        // For each element in the input array, check it,
        // and increment the count if it is prime.
        if(primeCheck(a[i]))
            ++numberPrime;
    }
    return numberPrime;
}
```

You can also use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) like this:

```
std::count_if(std::begin(input), std::end(input), primeCheck)
```

See it live [here](http://ideone.com/7OgorK).

Comment: … and if you’re writing a dedicated function anyway, you can also use [`std::count_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) to simplify your code.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Good suggestion, thanks, I will edit it into my answer in a minute. Just started with what (s)he already had.

Comment: One simple optimization: `for(int d = 2; (d*d)<=p; ++d) { /* ... */ }`. Of course, then there's the chance that `d*d` overflows that needs to be considered...

Comment: @MichaelBurr I didn't want to go down that road, it's a whole book at least. Just going for correct.

Comment: @BoBTFish Thanks! :) For those who are confused by the `size` template in the example code (like I was – `(&)`?!), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368883/how-does-this-size-of-array-template-function-work)’s the explanation.

Comment: @RobinKrahl Ah sorry about that. It's a handy little trick that will be in The Standard from 2017, but the syntax is a bit funky. I didn't bother explaining since it's not really part of the question. `std::begin` and `std::end` for arrays work a similar way.

Comment: optimization?  for(int d = 2; d<=p/2; ++d)

Comment: @RadijatoR The optimization suggested by Michael Burr is better.