# How to get the length of array while overloading the = operator

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

```
class myclass{
//definitions here
};
myclass e;
int myarray[10];
/*
Do something...
*/
e = myarray;
```

In order to make `e = myarray` possible, I overloaded the = operator. And I have to get the length of the  incoming array length.

```
template <class T>
int getarrlen(T& arr)
{
    return sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
}

myclass::operator=(int obj[]) {
    int len=getarrlen(obj);
    //Do something...
}
```

But the return value of `getarrlen(obj)` is always 1.

**So, how can I get the length of obj[] in the overloading function?**
By the way, I've also tried `int size = *(&arr + 1) - arr;` and it didn't work either.

**Update0:**
For this:

```
template<typename T1, int size>
int getarrlen(T1(&)[size]) { return size; }
```

I got a [C2784 compiler-error in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2784?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DZH-CN%26k%3Dk(C2784)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019)... Strange...
**Update1:**
The code provided by the link from @AlgirdasPreidžius works for the main function, but it doesn't work for my code:(
Also, to make it more obvious, I've tried this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int x[10];
//Begin of the copied code
template <std::size_t N>
struct type_of_size
{
    typedef char type[N];
};

template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
typename type_of_size<Size>::type& sizeof_array_helper(T(&)[Size]);

#define sizeof_array(pArray) sizeof(sizeof_array_helper(pArray))
//End
void myv(int a[]) {
    const std::size_t n = sizeof_array(a); // constant-expression!
    cout << n << endl;
}

int main() {
    int a[20] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    myv(a);
}
```

The code doesn't work. And I've tried to add  `template <typename T, std::size_t Size>` above `void myv(int a[]) {` and it didn't work work either...

Comment: Your template for deducing the array length is wrong. Have a look at this question: [How does this “size of array” template function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368883/how-does-this-size-of-array-template-function-work)

Comment: That won't work, you need to get the array *size* as a template argument as well. How to do it is shown and easily found all over the Internet.

Comment: `myclass::operator=(std::pair<int*, size_t> ptr_and_len)`

Comment: With the answer in the link provided by @AlgirdasPreidžius MSCV doesn't seem to have a problem: [Demo on CompilerExplorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/BnBKxx)

Comment: use the same template overload for `operator=` as you did for sizeof (after fixing the latter...)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Maybe I am mistaken in my answer below, but I do not need the size as template parameter. The compiler knows it and can deduce it automatically for us. Right?

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a solution that allows you to do assignments as shown on the top of your questions.

I implemented an assignment operator and a copy constructor with the same mechanism. I will work only for C-Style `int` arrays at the moment, because the `std::vector<int>` the class contains ints.

We need to use templates so that the Compiler has a chance to deduce types.

The software has bee tested with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.5.2.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Test {
    // The data. At the moment fixed to "int"
    std::vector<int> data{};

    // Default constructor
    Test() {}

    // Copy constructor
    template<typename T>
    Test(T& t) {

        // Number of Elements
        size_t size = (sizeof (decltype(t))) / (sizeof (std::remove_extent<std::remove_reference<decltype(t)>::type>::type));
        // Copy the data
        data.clear();
        std::copy_n(&t[0], size, std::back_inserter(data));
    }

    // Assignment operator
    template<typename T>
    Test &operator =(T& t) {

        // Number of Elements
        size_t size = (sizeof(decltype(t))) / (sizeof(std::remove_extent<std::remove_reference<decltype(t)>::type>::type));
        // Copy the data
        data.clear();
        std::copy_n(&t[0], size, std::back_inserter(data));
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {

    // Some simple Lambda to print the contents of an STL container
    auto print = [](const auto& container) -> void { std::copy(container.begin(), container.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::decay<decltype(*container.begin())>::type>(std::cout, " ")); std::cout << '\n'; };

    // Define an Plain C-Style array
    int a[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    // Define instance of class
    Test t1;
    // Assignment
    t1 = a;

    print(t1.data);

    // Define instance of another class and use copy constructor
    Test t2(a);

    print(t2.data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don’t recommend overloading `operator =` for an arbitrary type. Instead you should probably overload it for reference-to-array only.

Comment: I would never do that, but it is answering the question of the OP. You should comment on the question of the OP instead . . .

Comment: My comment isn’t about OP’s question (which is reasonable, though gets confused about the difference between arrays and pointers).