# How are Missing Template Arguments Deduced when Function Argument is a 2D Array

Tags: c++

Consider

```
#include <iostream>

// Print n x m - Matrix A
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void printMatrix(T (&A)[N][M]) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) { // Rows
        for(int j=0; j<M; ++j) { // Columns
            std::cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int A[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };

    printMatrix(A);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The code works and I can see that `T` is deduced from the argument but I'm wondering how exactly the compiler deduces the values of `N` and `M`.

Comment: The same way it deduces `T`?

Comment: `T` is deduced from  `A` whereas `A` is explicitly given. So that's clear. But `N` and `M` are "properties" of `A`. If I read `printMatrix(A)` I see one variable and that's `A` so for me it's not obvious that the compiler know what `N` and `M` refer to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does this "size of array" template function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368883/how-does-this-size-of-array-template-function-work)

Comment: The compiler knows not only the name of an object, `A` but also its type. This is fundamental to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better understand the situation, let's use lower-case variable names:

```
template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void printMatrix(T (&a)[N][M]) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) { // Rows
        for(int j=0; j<M; ++j) { // Columns
            std::cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[2][2] = { {1,2},{3,4} };

    printMatrix(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

(`A` was changed to `a`). Now let's observe, that the type of `a` is `int[2][2]`. This is the type that gets inferred by the compiler, that is also capable of breaking it down into components.