# std::vector versus std::array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What are the difference between a `std::vector` and an `std::array` in C++? When should one be preferred over another? What are the pros and cons of each? All my textbook does is list how they are the same.

Comment: I'm looking for a comparison of `std::vector` vs. `std::array` and how the terms are different.

Comment: Zud, `std::array` is not the same as a C++ array. `std::array` is a very thin wrapper around C++ arrays, with the primary purpose of hiding the pointer from the user of the class. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated the question title and text to reflect your clarification.

Comment: If you are implementing constexpr or consteval function then you can use std::array, but can't use std::vector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241909/cannot-create-constexpr-stdvector

Answer (score 413, accepted):

`std::vector` is a template class that encapsulate a dynamic array<sup>1</sup>, stored in the heap, that grows and shrinks automatically if elements are added or removed. It provides all the hooks (`begin()`, `end()`, iterators, etc) that make it work fine with the rest of the STL. It also has several useful methods that let you perform operations that on a normal array would be cumbersome, like e.g. inserting elements in the middle of a vector (it handles all the work of moving the following elements behind the scenes).

Since it stores the elements in memory allocated on the heap, it has some overhead in respect to static arrays.

`std::array` is a template class that encapsulate a statically-sized array, stored inside the object itself, which means that, if you instantiate the class on the stack, the array itself will be on the stack. Its size has to be known at compile time (it's passed as a template parameter), and it cannot grow or shrink.

It's more limited than `std::vector`, but it's often more efficient, especially for small sizes, because in practice it's mostly a lightweight wrapper around a C-style array. However, it's more secure, since the implicit conversion to pointer is disabled, and it provides much of the STL-related functionality of `std::vector` and of the other containers, so you can use it easily with STL algorithms & co. Anyhow, for the very limitation of fixed size it's much less flexible than `std::vector`.

For an introduction to `std::array`, have a look at [this article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdarray/); for a quick introduction to `std::vector` and to the the operations that are possible on it, you may want to look at its [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

---

1. <s>Actually, I think that in the standard they are described in terms of maximum complexity of the different operations (e.g. random access in constant time, iteration over all the elements in linear time, add and removal of elements at the end in constant amortized time, etc), but AFAIK there's no other method of fulfilling such requirements other than using a dynamic array.</s> As stated by @Lucretiel, the standard actually requires that the elements are stored contiguously, so *it is* a dynamic array, stored where the associated allocator puts it.

Comment: Regarding your footnote: While true, the standard also guarentees that pointer arithmetic on the internal elements works, which means that it does have to be an array: &vec[9] - &vec[3] == 6 is true.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that vector doesn't shrink automatically, but since C++11 you can call shrink_to_fit.

Comment: I'm totally confused by the term _static array_ and I'm not sure what the right terminology is. You mean a static size array and not an static variable array (one using static storage). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672085/c-static-array-vs-dynamic-array/26466627#26466627. What is the correct terminology? Is static array a sloppy term for an array with a fixed size?

Comment: @Zboson: I mean a statically-*sized* array; sorry, I agree that the terminology is confusing, I'll fix it immediately.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, okay, so it's not just me. I'm not trying to be pedantic. It's just that I read a x86 assembly manual recently and it used a static array as one defined in the data/BSS section but it seems on SO most questions/answers assume a static array is an automatic variable array.

Comment: @Zboson: it's definitely not just you, *static* is quite an abused term; the very `static` keyword in C++ has three different unrelated meanings, and the term is also used often to talk about stuff that is fixed at compile time. I hope that "statically-sized" is a bit more clear.

Comment: @Dino, `std::shrink_to_fit` does not guarantee a shrinking, it may shrink the vector, but it's not 100% guaranteed.

Comment: would performance of vector be comparable to array if both are on the heap?

Comment: One thing to note: For real-time programming (where you aren't supposed to have **any** dynamic allocation/deallocation after startup) std::array would probably be preferred over std::vector.

Comment: I cannot figure out how the [bench-mark](http://quick-bench.com/wOn8IPnv4DxsicBwacFZJsJNjuw) shows opposite.

Comment: @ar2015 May be because in the example, the vector is not resized dynamically?

Comment: @T.E.D. You could also use std::vector with a custom allocator, which might be a better option than std::array eating the stack.

Comment: Thank you for the nice and comprehensive answer! What do you mean by saying: "but it's often more efficient, especially for small sizes". Why do you think efficiency gains are diminished with larger sizes? What would you classify as small sized ?

Comment: @fabian indeed that statement isn't very precise... the general idea is that (at first approximation) we can imagine the cost of a dynamic allocation as roughly fixed, but for big sizes generally it's going to be dwarfed by the computation you are going to do on the memory. OTOH, for a small scratch buffer that is going just as temporary storage it may become the dominant cost. Also, doing a ton of small allocs/deallocs generally hurts the overall performance of the allocator (if not tuned specifically for it), so it's something you often want to avoid if possible.

Answer (score 33):

To emphasize a point made by @MatteoItalia, the efficiency difference is where the data is stored.  Heap memory (required with `vector`) requires a call to the system to allocate memory and this can be expensive if you are counting cycles.  Stack memory (possible for `array`) is virtually "zero-overhead" in terms of time, because the memory is allocated by just adjusting the stack pointer and it is done just once on entry to a function.  The stack also avoids memory fragmentation.  To be sure, `std::array` won't always be on the stack; it depends on where you allocate it, but it will still involve one less memory allocation from the heap compared to vector.  If you have a

- small "array" (under 100 elements say) - (a typical stack is about 8MB, so don't allocate more than a few KB on the stack or less if your code is recursive)
- the size will be fixed
- the lifetime is in the function scope (or is a member value with the same lifetime as the parent class)
- you are counting cycles,

definitely use a `std::array` over a vector. If any of those requirements is not true, then use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Nice answer. "To be sure, std::array won't always be on the stack; it depends on where you allocate it" So how could I create a std::array not on the stack with a large number of elements?

Comment: @Trilarion use `new std::array` or make it a member of a class that you use 'new` to allocate.

Comment: So this means `new std::array` still expects to know its size at compile time and cannot change its size but still lives on the heap?

Comment: Yes. There isn't a significant advantage to using `new std::array` vs `new std::vector`.

Answer (score 31):

Summarizing the above discussion in a table for quick reference:

|  | C-Style Array | std::array | std::vector |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Size** | Fixed/Static | Fixed/Static | Dynamic |
| **Memory efficiency** | More efficient | More Efficient | Less efficient (May double its size on new allocation.) |
| **Copying** | Iterate over elements or use `std::copy()` | Direct copy: `a2 = a1;` | Direct copy: `v2 = v1;` |
| **Passing to function** | Passed by pointer (size not available in function) or as `std::span` | Passed by value or as `std::span` | Passed by value or as `std::span` |
| **Size** | `sizeof a1 / sizeof *a1` or `std::size(a1)` | `a1.size()` or `std::size(a1)` | `v1.size()` or `std::size(v1)` |
| **Use case** | For quick access and when insertions/deletions not frequently needed. | Same as classic array but safer and easier to pass and copy. | When frequent additions or deletions might be needed |

Comment: `void foo(T (& arr)[N])` would capture array size. similar [magic-arguments-in-function-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384107/magic-arguments-in-function-templates)

Comment: I would add these rows:  "| Value semantics | no | yes | yes |" and "| Move | O(N) | O(N) | O(1) |" and "| Swap | O(N) | O(N) | O(1) |"

Comment: What exactly is "Memory efficiency"? The expression can be ambiguous. Also, how the capacity of `std::vector` gets increased on new allocation *depends on implementation*. E.g. MSVC increases the capacity by x1.5, not x2.

Comment: @starriet주녕차 It sounds clear to me. `std::vector` is _less efficient_ in that the memory it allocates may not fit the size of the data it stores, and _less performant_ because it does multiple memory allocations, which is costly.

Answer (score 26):

If you are considering using multidimensional arrays, then there is one additional difference between `std::array` and `std::vector`. A multidimensional `std::array` will have the elements packed in memory in all dimensions, just as a C style array is. A multidimensional `std::vector` will not be packed in all dimensions.

Given the following declarations:

```cpp
int cConc[3][5];
std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 3> aConc;
int **ptrConc; // initialized to [3][5] via new and destructed via delete
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vConc; // initialized to [3][5]
```

A pointer to the first element in the C-style array (cConc) or the `std::array` (aConc) can be iterated through the entire array by adding 1 to each preceding element. They are tightly packed.

A pointer to the first element in the vector array (vConc) or the pointer array (ptrConc) can only be iterated through the first 5 (in this case) elements, and then there are 12 bytes (on my system) of overhead for the next vector.

This means that a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` array initialized as a `[3][1000]` array will be much smaller in memory than one initialized as a `[1000][3]` array, and both will be larger in memory than a `std::array` allocated either way.

This also means that you can't simply pass a multidimensional vector (or pointer) array to, say, OpenGL without accounting for the memory overhead, but you can naively pass a multidimensional `std::array` to OpenGL and have it work out.

Answer (score 21):

Using the `std::vector<T>` class:

- ...is *just as fast* as using built-in arrays, assuming you are doing only the things built-in arrays allow you to do (read and write to existing elements).
- ...automatically resizes when new elements are inserted.
- ...allows you to insert new elements *at the beginning* or *in the middle* of the vector, automatically "shifting" the rest of the elements "up"( does that make sense?). It allows you to remove elements anywhere in the `std::vector`, too, automatically shifting the rest of the elements down.
- ...allows you to perform a range-checked read with the `at()` method (you can always use the indexers `[]` if you don't want this check to be performed).

There are <strike>two</strike> three main caveats to using `std::vector<T>`:

1. You don't have reliable access to the underlying pointer, which *may* be an issue if you are dealing with third-party functions that demand the address of an array.
2. The `std::vector<bool>` class is silly. It's implemented as a condensed bitfield, not as an array. Avoid it if you want an array of `bool`s!
3. During usage, `std::vector<T>`s are going to be a bit larger than a C++ array with the same number of elements. This is because they need to keep track of a small amount of other information, such as their current size, and because whenever `std::vector<T>`s resize, they reserve more space then they need. This is to prevent them from having to resize every time a new element is inserted. This behavior can be changed by providing a custom `allocator`, but I never felt the need to do that!

---

Edit: After reading Zud's reply to the question, I felt I should add this:

The `std::array<T>` class is not the same as a C++ array. `std::array<T>` is a very thin wrapper around C++ arrays, with the primary purpose of hiding the pointer from the user of the class (in C++, arrays are implicitly cast as pointers, often to dismaying effect). The `std::array<T>` class also stores its size (length), which can be very useful.

Comment: It's 'just as fast" as using a dynamically-allocated built-in array.  On the other hand, using an automatic array might have considerably different performance (and not only during allocation, because of locality effects).

Comment: For non-bool vectors in C++11 and later, you can call `data()` on a `std::vector<T>` to get the underlying pointer. You can also just take the address of element 0 (guaranteed to work with C++11, will probably work with earlier versions).

Comment: In last paragraph you mean C array ? Right ?

Answer (score -19):

A vector is a container class while an array is an allocated memory.

Comment: Your answer seems to address `std::vector<T>` versus `T[]`, but the question is about `std::vector<T>` versus `std::array<T>`.