# Passing static array to function in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

With the defined function as...

```
void func (int a [3]) { ... }
```

I'd like to be able to pass a dynamic static array like so

```
func (new int [3] {1,2,3});
```

instead of...

```
int temp [3] = {1,2,3};
func(temp);
```

Is this possible with C++?

Comment: You should really try and research on your own before posting here.

Comment: And keep in mind that C++ is not garbage collected...

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 I have, but I haven't been able to find a post telling me explicitly that I can't do this. I just don't understand how the compiler can't put that on the stack.

Comment: @ixe013 But that's fine here though right? Because it's on the stack, not the heap.

Comment: @xori : `new` _means_ heap (by default).

Comment: @xori: `new` == dynamic memory allocation (unless it's been overloaded to do something else, but that's probably not the case here).  Some objects have automatic storage duration (i.e., "on the stack" in practical terms, but the stack is an implementation detail) and some have to be managed by you. In this case you are leaking memory.

Comment: The pointer to the memory is put on the stack. The memory itself is not, you must manage it. Follow @JesseGood advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a C++11 compiler, `func (new int [3] {1,2,3});` would work fine (but, remember that you are responsible for `delete`ing the memory). With gcc, just pass the `-std=c++11` flag.

However, look into `std::array` so you don't have to use `new`:

**Example**

```
void func (std::array<int, 3> a)
{
}

int main()
{
    func({{1, 2, 3}});
}
```

Comment: "would work fine" as in "the code runs and produces the expected output, but leaks memory because there is no matching call to `delete` in the example"

Comment: @EdS.: Right, I added a note about that.

Comment: So does the compiler put that declaration on the heap?

Comment: @xori: `std::array` is fixed at compile time and is on the stack.

Comment: @xori: an instance of `std::array` is allocated with automatic storage duration ("the stack"), but it allocates its data store dynamically.  You don't have to worry about it though as it will clean up after itself.

Comment: @EdS.: The elements of `std::array` are on the stack if you instantiate `std::array` on the stack. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/c-stdvector-vs-stdarray). It's basically a `struct` with an array as a member.

Comment: Oh wow, now *that* I did not know, thanks. I can't say I've ever actually used std::array, but I routinely learn new things browsing around questions here.  Thanks again. +1

Answer (score 2):

It works on my compiler (Eclipse indigo with CDT extension), but it gives a warning that implies it may not work in all environments:

extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]

Here's my test code:

```
void func (int a[3])
{
cout << a[2];
}

int main()
{
    func(new int[3]{1,3,8});
}
```

successfully prints "8" to the console.

Answer (score 2):

Your example with `new int [3] {1,2,3}` works just fine, but it allocates an array on the heap each time it is called.

You should be able to do it on the stack using a typecast:

```
func((int[]){1,2,3});
```

Comment: I believe `(int[]){1,2,3}` is only in C (it's a compound literal).

Comment: @JesseGood GCC supports compound literals in C++, though the semantics are somewhat different than in C.

Comment: it works with `const` ... e.g. `double arr_func( int n, const double * xs ){ }; arr_func( 3, (const double[]){1.0,2.0,3.0} );`