# Pros/Cons of using STL lists and vectors, linked lists and arrays

Tags: arrays, list, data-structures, vector, linked-list

I'm wondering what the difference is between STL:list, STL:vector, array and linked list on a basic level in comparison to one another.

My understanding is that, generally, linked lists allow for grow-able lists, inserts and deletes are much easier but it takes longer to direct access a single element in the linked list since you would need to traverse through every element.

I am probably missing many other key differences so you could also point some more obvious ones out as well.

How do lists and vectors come into play in comparison and when would you choose one over the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::vector versus std::array in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c)

Comment: tl;dr: use vectors – it’ll be the right tool 99% of the time. Linked lists are almost never beneficial.

Comment: Please note it's not called the Standard Template Library anymore.  It's the C++ Standard Library.

Comment: I marked the wrong duplicate.  Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209224/vector-vs-list-in-stl

Comment: possible duplicate of [LInked List vs Vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039972/linked-list-vs-vector)

Answer (score 1):

Below are some differences between lists and vectors.

1. **Time taken for Insertion:** Lists take constant time to insert an
   element into them, where as vectors internally need to relocate the
   data present in the vector before inserting a new value if the
   capacity of vector is equal to number of elements present in the
   vector. This takes a overhead to the processor and time.
2. **Time taken to access the data**: Vectors has upper hand over lists in
   this aspect. Vector takes constant time to access elements present
   at the middle. Where as lists need to traverse through the list to
   reach the required element.
3. **Memory taken by the container:** The capacity and size of vector
   necessarily need not be same. The capacity of vector grows
   exponentially intern consuming more memory than actually needed by
   the container. Lists take exactly same memory required to store
   elements, hence no extra memory is allocated during allocation by
   which you can save memory.