# std::array vs std::vector subtle difference

Tags: arrays, c++11, vector

I wanted to mess around with `std::array` to see how different it is from `std::vector`. So far, I've only found one major difference.

```
Sentence sentence = { "Hello", "from", "GCC", __VERSION__, "!" };  
std::array<std::string, 10> a;
std::copy(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), a.begin());

int i = 0;
for (const auto& e : a)
{
    i++;
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
std::cout << i << std::endl;

// outputs 10

i = 0;
for (const auto& e : sentence)
{
    i++;
    std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
std::cout << i << std::endl;

// outputs 5

for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    std::cout << i << " " << a[i] << std::endl;

// outputs 0 Hello
// ...
//         4 !
//         5-9 is blank

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.size(); i++)
    std::cout << i << " " << sentence[i] << std::endl;

// outputs 0 Hello
// ...
//         4 !
// stops here


// The following outputs the same as above
i = 0;

for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << i << " " << *it << std::endl;
    i++;
}
std::cout << i << std::endl;
i = 0;
for (auto it = sentence.begin(); it != sentence.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << i << " " << *it << std::endl;   
    i++;
}
std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

So from what I can see, `std::array`'s `size` and `max_size` is redundant, but `std::vector`'s `size` and `capacity` can be different or the same. This is even confirmed from this quote:

> size and max_size of an array object always match.

So why does `std::array` have redundant size functions? More importantly, would you consider it a gotcha that `std::array`'s size is not necessarily the same as `std::vector`'s size, because the vector has a capacity? Also, does this mean that `std::array`s are safe (i.e., do they have smart pointer management like vectors?)

Comment: The last sentences makes me think that you may have some confusion about what a `std::array` actually is; maybe have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c/4424658#4424658) for a quick comparison.

Comment: You might think that resizability or lack thereof, and dynamic vs static allocation were bigger differences...  Also, needing the size as a template argument (which enables static allocation)

Comment: The difference between `std::array` and `std::vector` is FAR from subtle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`capacity` in  `vector` is the max capacity of a `vector`..which may or may not be same as its `size`. 
`size` is the current number of elements in `vector`.

For performance reasons, if you know the max size of the vector in advance (or have a guess), you can pre-determine the vector's capacity (rather than using its default value). This may significantly increase your code's performance as you would not have to reallocate on each iteration (when you add elements).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/capacity/

Answer (score 6):

To make it compatible with the other containers.

This way you can have a template function which takes any collection and be sure it will work the same no matter if it's a `std::vector` or an `std::array`.

Answer (score 2):

The more important difference is that `std::vector` has a `resize` function, whereas `std::array` does not.

The size of a `std::array` instance (like that of a normal array) is fixed when it is instantiated (in fact its size must be known at compile-time, and be a constant expression).  A `std::vector` instance however can be resized after it has been instantiated during run-time.

Further `std::arrays` of different sizes are distinct types, whereas `std::vectors` of different sizes are the same type.

The only reason to use a `std::array` over a `std::vector`, is that a `std::array` uses less space and is faster.  A `std::vector` needs to store its size and a pointer to a heap-allocated backing store which may have extra padding to allow for resizing.  A `std::array` is allocated in-place (no indirect pointer), and its `size` function is also known statically so a call to `std::array.size()` will compile to a constant (it is a `constexpr` function in fact).

Answer (score 1):

To expand a little, on the subject an `std::array` follows very closely to the actual design of an array such as `char[]` in which the max-size of the array is the size of the array. This is because the array can be thought of as having an immutable size. That is a size that can not be changed besides completely reallocating the memory. Unlike a `std::vector` which can be set to have a `capacity` and a size that can be anywhere from 0 to that `capacity`, however once it passes that `capacity` value each new element will cause a complete recreation and allocation of the underlying array inside of the `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, a `std::array` is always the same size. `size() == capacity()`. That means when you create a `std::array<T, 5>`, you get five calls to `T`'s default constructor. A `std::vector<T>`, on the other hand will not default-construct any elements. Calling `reserve(5)` on the vector will still not cause any items to be constructed.

Neither `std::array` nor `std::vector` have "smart pointer management", at least in the way I think about them. They both provide iterator types, and functions like `begin/end/rbegin/rend` that let you traverse the elements in the container. When people say "smart pointer", I think about `shared_ptr/unique_ptr/auto_ptr/etc`.

In general, a `std::array` is stored on the stack, while a `std::vector` allocates storage on the heap. In performance critical applications, that is a big advantage for `std::array`. Allocating memory on the heap can be 100s or 1000s of times slower than using the stack, especially in multithreaded applications.