# How is std::vector faster than a plain array?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, stl

I stumbled across this while benchmarking a circular buffer. Can anyone explain how a std::vector manages to outperform a plain array in this instance?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct uint_pair {
    unsigned int a, b;
    uint_pair (unsigned int x = 0, unsigned int y = 0) : a(x), b(y) {}
};

struct container {
    unsigned int pos;

#ifdef USE_VECTOR
    std::vector<uint_pair> data;
    container() : pos(0) { data.resize(16); }
#else
    uint_pair data[16];
    container() : pos(0) {}
#endif

    void add(uint_pair val) {
        data[++pos % 16] = val;
    }
};

int main() {
    container c;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) c.add(uint_pair{i, i});
    std::cout << c.data[0].a << " " << c.data[0].b << std::endl;
}
```

These are the results I'm getting using GCC (similar with Clang):

```
g++ -o bench -std=c++0x -Os main.cpp -D'USE_VECTOR'
real    0m8.757s
user    0m8.750s
sys     0m0.002s

g++ -o bench -std=c++0x -Os main.cpp
real    0m9.215s
user    0m9.209s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Comment: Could be just the way allocations line up with other data in the cache. P.S. you want `resize` not `reserve`.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, updated the code. Results still hold though.

Comment: GCC 4.8 brings an even larger difference. I see 0.6s for vector and 1.8s for array. Optimization level matters, -O3 gets 0.9s for the vector.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that somehow for the vector it holds the buffer address in a register, but somehow fails to do that for the raw array. Check out the machine code. Try with a pointer to array instead of array directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::vector versus std::array in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think that's precisely correct. With the array, it knows it can compute the offset on the stack, but that's not quite as easy as having the pointer to the actual start. The inner loop is two instructions longer.

Comment: TIL you can "bench" something from command-line :o  All this time I used platform specific high performance timers to bench my code.. The `vector` should be slower since it `memset` all the elements to 0/default right?

Comment: @Brandon there are only 16 elements. The initialization time is negligible.

Comment: There was a half-right answer that was just deleted but that had a good observation. The array elements are in your `container` struct, while the vector elements are somewhere else and accessed through a pointer. That has some effect on optimization as well. You can narrow the gap by changing your array to a `uint_pair*` and allocate it in the constructor. In my test that doubles its performance, but it's still a little slower than a vector.

Comment: Look at the assembly for each.

Comment: Tried it with another compiler, the disassembly showed the problem.  Issue is that the array is stored in the same class of memory as the loop variable, the compiler is conservative about aliasing assumptions and treated the loop variable volatile.  Not an issue with vector, it is stored on the heap instead of the stack.  Using uint_pair* data instead of uint_pair data[16] eliminated the difference.

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you can eliminate the difference. Instead of your `add`, use a function like this:

```
void set(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    ++pos;
    data[pos % 16].a = x;
    data[pos % 16].b = y;
}
```

called like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) c.set(i, i);
```

This does exactly the same thing as yours, but it avoids semantically creating a temporary object. It looks like when you use a vector the compiler is better able to optimize out the temporary.

```
$ g++-4.8 -o bench -std=c++11 -Os main.cpp -DUSE_VECTOR
$ time ./bench 
999999999 999999999

real    0m0.635s
user    0m0.630s
sys 0m0.002s

$ g++-4.8 -o bench -std=c++11 -Os main.cpp
$ time ./bench 
999999999 999999999

real    0m0.644s
user    0m0.639s
sys 0m0.002s
```

On my machine both the `set` and `add` methods yield identical performance with vectors. Only the array shows a difference. To further lend credence to optimization, if you compile with -O0 then the array method is slightly faster (but both over 10x slower than with -Os).

This doesn't explain *why* the compiler treats these two differently. A vector is, after all, backed by an array. Also, an `std::array` behaves identically to your C-style array.

Comment: Interestingly, performance wise, `std::array` is more like using the C-style array than using `std::vector`.

Comment: @5gon12eder correct, it's just a STL-like wrapper around a C-style array. I tried that too, and in this case it behaves just like the C-style array.

Comment: On my machine, I observe somewhat different results.  The loop for the `std::vector` has always 5 instructions.  The array needs 7 with the OP's code but only 4 with yours, so it's even faster (also backed by timing results) than `std::vector`.  `std::array` always produces identical assembly code than the C-style array.  [GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease) on x86_64 GNU/Linux]

Answer (score 2):

One problem is with the placement of the "pos" member in your struct.

For the c-array, remember that it is stored contiguously in memory adjacent to your "pos" member. When data is pushed into the c-array, extra instructions have to be issued to offset into the structure past the "pos" member. However, writing to the vector makes no such restriction since its memory is located elsewhere.

To squeeze out more performance, make sure your hottest data is at the front of a cache line.

**Edit:**

To get the c-array to perform just as fast as the vector, the c-array must be allocated on 8 byte boundaries on a 64 bit machine. So something like:

```
uint_pair* data;
unsigned int pos;

container() : pos(0) {
    std::size_t bufSize = sizeof(uint_pair) * 17;
    void* p = new char[bufSize];
    p = std::align(8, sizeof(uint_pair), p, bufSize);
    data = reinterpret_cast<uint_pair*>(p);
}
```

With a slightly modified add function:

```
void add(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) {
    auto& ref = data[pos++ % 16];
    ref.a = x;
    ref.b = y;
}
```

The c-array now times:

```
real    0m0.735s
user    0m0.730s
sys     0m0.002s
```

And the std::vector:

```
real    0m0.743s
user    0m0.736s
sys     0m0.004s
```

The standard library implementers are pulling out all the stops for you :)

Comment: Your claim is that the problem is the memory alignment, but you don't show that. You used a similar `add` function that I did, and I show that that change alone erases the performance difference. So the alignment changes have no effect at all (in other words, the compiler already took care of that).

Comment: You are right, there is a difference between an array that's built into the structure and one accessed through a pointer. But that does not explain the entire performance difference (see my comment on the original question). I'd also like to see some proof for your cache claim. The data totals less than 20 ints. All approaches should be in cache.

Comment: We must be getting different results. Using your "set" or my altered "add," the performance difference between the heap-allocated c-array and the std::vector is **not** equal -- there is still a ~0.04s slowdown on the c-array.

This difference can be completely eliminated using a properly aligned heap allocation, which is something the compiler will not do for you, by the way. Hence, both the modified "add" as well as the aligned heap allocation are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It seems C++11 compiler generates better code for vector because of operator=(rvalue reference).
Firstly, In C++03 compiler plain array twice faster than vector.
Secondly, tehre are no difference if you use void set(unsigned int x, unsigned int y) suggested by Adam.

Assembler code for vector

```
.L49:
leal    (%rdi,%rax), %esi
andl    $15, %esi
leaq    (%rdx,%rsi,8), %rsi
movl    %eax, (%rsi)
movl    %eax, 4(%rsi)
incq    %rax
cmpq    $1000000000, %rax
jne .L49
```

for plain array

```
.L3:
movl    12(%rsp), %edx
incl    %edx
movl    %edx, 12(%rsp)
andl    $15, %edx
leaq    12(%rsp,%rdx,8), %rdx
movl    %eax, 4(%rdx)
movl    %eax, 8(%rdx)
incl    %eax
cmpl    $1000000000, %eax
jne .L3
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that a move kicks in. First of all `uint_pair` declares a constructor, so it does not have a default move constructor. Second: the parameter of the `operator=` in the `add` function is an lvalue. Third: even defining a move ctor, the two unsigned members would still have to be copied.