# Algorithm complexities and stl::vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

Suppose :

```
int arr[10]; // you have O(n ) linear algorithm for search
```

but when you use :

```
std::vector<int> V;
```

**Question is :** What's Algorithm complexity for searching behind of impelentation of vector?

Comment: `std::vector` has constant time random access, so it's the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::vector versus std::array in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Searching in an array and `std::vector` is `O( n )` not `O( log n )`

`O( log n )` will be achieved only when array/`std::vector` is sorted.

`std::vector` implementation doesn't include any searching algorithm, however to get `O( log n )` you first need to sort it and then perform  binary search, this is same as with an array too.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I don't think I need to update my post, IMHO you have pretty much changed your entire question now, anyway, for performing a search in `std::vector` you can use [_`std::find`_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)