# how to efficiently read a binary file into a vector C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, stdvector

I need to read a large binary file (~1GB) into a `std::vector<double>`. I'm currently using `infile.read` to copy the whole  thing into a `char *` buffer (shown below) and I currently plan to convert the whole thing into `doubles` with `reinterpret_cast`. surely there must be a way to just put the `doubles` straight into the `vector`?

I'm also not sure about the format of the binary file,  the data was produced in python so it's probably all floats

```
ifstream infile(filename, std--ifstream--binary);

infile.seekg(0, infile.end);     //N is the total number of doubles
N = infile.tellg();              
infile.seekg(0, infile.beg);

char * buffer = new char[N];

infile.read(buffer, N);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use doubles? Binary data is normally represented as a char since it, on most platforms, occupies a single byte.

Comment: If you don't know the format of the file how did you plan to convert it?

Comment: Ummmmm.... you want to read a binary file not knowing the format as something else than just a stream of bytes?

Comment: Map the file into memory, construct the vector from that.

Comment: Nobody has said anything about endianness yet.  Maybe portability doesn't matter in this case.  Also, asking the OS for 1GB of contiguous data is not generally a great idea.  Consider whether a container like `std::deque` would suit your requirements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the entire file is double, otherwise this wont work properly.

```
std::vector<double> buf(N / sizeof(double));// reserve space for N/8 doubles
infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), buf.size()*sizeof(double)); // or &buf[0] for C++98
```

Comment: The declaration zero-initialises, which seems a bit wasteful.

Comment: @AlanStokes On the other hand, the IO operation itself probably is the bottleneck. I would say this is fine until measurement proofs this to be significant.

Comment: You certainly do not want to (and most certainly cannot)  save 1GB of data in an `std::array`.

Comment: Btw, you also need to be sure the binary dump and `vector` backing storage use the same alingment. It *should* be safe with `double`... but should can blow up some sunny day.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Curious, why isn't std::array suitable for large data? Is the the storage on the stack?

Comment: @luk32, This is safe. You maybe thinking the reverse case where it's a std::vector<char> v and v.data() is being casted into a double*

Comment: @BaummitAugen 1GB isn't that much these days. Both `array` and `vector` store the data contiguously; why do you think there would be a problem?

Comment: @Alan Because various sources such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c or [here](http://binglongx.com/2011/05/08/c-and-c-arrays-on-stack-and-heap/) state it might be stored on stack (you need to work around for it to be allocated on heap). I cannot find any sources for this though =/

Comment: @Tony Not necessarily. This code assumes, the binary dump held in `infile` is compatible with the run-time environment. "*entire file is double*" is not precise enough.

Comment: @AlanStokes @TonyJiang Because `std::array` is (by design) a zero overhead wrapper for C-arrays (the `int arr[100];` kind). Those end up on the stack (unless it has `static` storage duration or allocated dynamically, but don't do the latter in this case).

Comment: I'm using std::vector to keep the data compatible with a load of pre-existing code I've been given to write around. I might swap the vectors for arrays once I've got everything else working

Comment: Isn't it undefined behavior to write to a reinterpreted char* unlike reading it?

Comment: @Asu No, it's no UB, because it's reading raw binary data into a buffer, which just happens to be a double* allocated in std::vector<double>.