# How to read a binary file into a vector of unsigned integer

Tags: c++

I'm making a sorting algorithm in C++ that gets data from a binary file. The file only contains unsigned int and the first 4byte of the file show the number of elements it has. Next 4byte chunks has the unsigned integer gotta be sorted.

```
    ifstream ifs(INPUT_FILE_NAME,ios::binary);
    ifs.seekg(0,ifs.end);
    int N=0;
    N=(int)ifs.tellg();
    vector<unsigned int> buf(N / sizeof(unsigned int));// reserve space for N/4 unsigned int
    ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), buf.size()*sizeof(unsigned int)); // char==byte
```

I referenced a question ["how to efficiently read a binary file into a vector C++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707928/how-to-efficiently-read-a-binary-file-into-a-vector-c), So, I tried to get bin file exactly into the vector. But I have no idea how to deal with it.
I tried to cast char into uint but it didn't work. Can you give me a hint to make it?

Comment: Also, since you are using the first 4 bytes of the file to provide the number of integers, you should rely on it for the size of the vector (you could double check with the file size) and skip it before adding the elements to the vector. Having the number of elements as the first value in the vector is counter productive as your first operation would be to remove it which would copy the whole vector.

Comment: You don't really need a count, if you trust the size of the file.

Comment: And you trust seek and tell to be implemented in a normal fashion. All they actually offer is the ability to return to a point in a stream, so you can get some deviant implementations that cannot be used to compute the size of a file. Don't know if I've seen one in the wild, though.

Comment: Thank you! Ill try getting first 4bytes!

Comment: For getting the file size, if you have C++17, there is this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size

Comment: Stackoverflow usage note: Avoid writing "It doesn't work" without describing how the behaviour you got deviated from the behaviour you expected.

Comment: Did you check that `unsigned int` is 32 bits on your system? Always worth validating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeking `ifs` to the end of the file, but you forgot to seek it back to the beginning before calling `read()`, so there is nothing for `read()` to read.  You need that 2nd seek, eg:

```
ifstream ifs(INPUT_FILE_NAME,ios::binary);

ifs.seekg(0, ifs.end);
size_t N = ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg(0, ifs.beg); // <-- ADD THIS!
```

For that matter, why are you seeking `ifs` at all? You said the 1st `unsigned int` in the file tells you the number of subsequent `unsigned int`s to read, so just read from `ifs` without seeking it at all, eg:

```
ifstream ifs(INPUT_FILE_NAME, ios::binary);

uint32_t N = 0;
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&N), sizeof(uint32_t));

vector<uint32_t> buf(N);
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), N * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

In which case, the 1st `unsigned int` becomes redundant if you are able to remove it, as you could just ask the filesystem for the file's size, eg:

```
ifstream ifs(INPUT_FILE_NAME, ios::binary);

vector<uint32_t> buf(filesystem::file_size(INPUT_FILE_NAME) / sizeof(uint32_t));
ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf.data()), buf.size() * sizeof(uint32_t));
```

Or, simply read from the file until EOF is reached, eg:

```
ifstream ifs(INPUT_FILE_NAME, ios::binary);

vector<uint32_t> buf;
buf.reserve(filesystem::file_size(INPUT_FILE_NAME) / sizeof(uint32_t));

uint32_t number;
while (ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&number), sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    buf.push_back(number);
}
```

Comment: I didn't think about the cursor!  and I didn't come up with an idea how to get the first 4bytes. Thanks for your help!