# How to initialize an empty global vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, global, declaration

I have a general question. Hopefully, one of you has a good approach to solve my problem. **How can I initialize an empty vector?**

As far as I read, one has to know the size of an array at compiling time, though for vectors it is different. Vectors are stored in the heap (e.g. here: [std::vector versus std::array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c))

In my program I want to let the client decide how accurate interpolation is going to be done. That's why I want to use vectors.

The problem is: For reasons of clear arrangement I want to write two methods:

- one method for calculating the coefficients of an vector and
- one method which is providing the coefficients to other functions.

Thus, I want to declare my vector as global and empty like

```
vector<vector<double>> vector1;
vector<vector<double>> vector2;
```

However, in the method where I determine the coefficients I cannot use

```
//vector containing coefficients for interpolation
/*vector<vector<double>>*/   vector1 (4, vector<double>(nn - 1));
for (int ii = 0; ii < nn - 1; ii++) {vector1[ii][0] = ...;
}
```

"nn" will be given by the client when running the program. So my question is how can I initialize an empty vector? Any ideas are appreciated!

Note please, if I call another function which by its definition gives back a vector as a return value I can write

```
vector2= OneClass.OneMethod(SomeInputVector);
```

where OneClass is an object of a class and OneMethod is a method in the class OneClass.

Note also, when I remove the comment /**/ in front of the vector, it is not global any more and throws me an error when trying to get access to the coefficients.

Comment: `std::vector<double> vec;` IS an empty vector!

Comment: Yes, but I want to "fill it" with variables. So how can I do that?

Comment: std::vector::push_back

Comment: I see the confusion, I'll edit the heading

Comment: What is up with the int ii, and nn in your for-loop? I think you should pick better naming variables or at least use a single character.

Comment: it doesn't matter where you declare the array. local, global, heap - without providing a size or initializer list it will be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Use `resize`:

```
vector1.resize(4, vector<double>(nn - 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [resize()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) function as follows:

```
vector<vector<double>> v;

int f(int nn){
   v.resize(4);
   for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      v[i].resize(nn - 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It look to me that you're actually asking how to add items to your global vector. If so this might help:

```
//vector containing coefficients for interpolation
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)  
    vector1.push_back(vector<double>(nn - 1));

for (int ii = 0; ii < nn - 1; ii++) 
{
    vector1[ii][0] = ...;
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. But actually your code simply provides me an one dimensional vector. So I need to figure out how to implement the second dimension. I already tried
    std::move(vector<vector<double>> (4, vector<double> (nn - 1)))
but it didnt work out.
Also using a for loop where I write
vector1[ii].push_back..
does not work
* I programmed without std:: just not to confuse I wrote it here again

Comment: ok.. I got the answer:

Somehow I forgot the first for loop... thank you!

Comment: @PublicUserName, there is no real multidimentional vector in standard c++. What you declare is one-dimentional vector of vectors which for most purposes is as good as mutlidimentional. My code fills the outer vector with 4 vectors of length nn-1 forming the data structure you need.

Answer (score -1):

Unsure if it is what you want, but assign could be interesting :

```
vector<vector<double>> vector1; // initialises an empty vector

// later in the code : 
vector<double> v(nn -1, 0.); // creates a local vector of size 100 initialized with 0.
vector1.assign(4, v);  // vector1 is now a vector of 4 vectors of 100 double (currently all 0.)
```