# Read 'large' data file in C++

Tags: c++, database, stream

I am trying to reproduce a old R Code I had into C++ in order to gain some speed. 
This code require the use of preloaded data (6 matrices of dimension 13689 x 126) (each of them weight about 28 MB in the .txt file). It did not cause any problem with R to have this loaded in the memory.

I built a C++ code (I am new to C++) where I try to 'pre-load' these data (is there anyway to pre-load it in the header file btw?).

```
int i, j;
const int length_grid1 = 13689; 
const int length_grid_pl = 126; 

ifstream in;
//double M1_BETA[length_grid1][length_grid_pl]; // either this, or the other one
std::array<std::array<int, length_grid_pl>, length_grid1> M1_BETA;
in.open("preloaded_object/M1_BETA.txt");
for (i = 0; i < length_grid1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < length_grid_pl; j++) { 
        in >> M1_BETA[i][j];
    }
}
in.close();
```

Both versions, using double or array do not work: I can compile the file (using Intel Composer), but when I launch the .exe, it instantly crashes. This happens with only one of the matrix loaded... And I must load 6 of them.

I don t think it is a problem coming from my code, when I reduce the data dimension it executes itself without any problem.
Notice that I cannot run the program afterwards if everything is not loaded. And reloading it part by part would reduce the pace too much I think (and I switched to C++ in order to gain computation speed..).

Is the program crashing because 28MB is too much? Seems weird because R does not have any problem for example...

Otherwise, can I preload in a way such that it takes less place in memory? I need to have easy access ton any row of the data afterwards (cell by cell is not so important, what I need is really to access specific rows really quickly).

Or is there even another way in C++ to store data, usable at any time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `std::array<std::array<int, length_grid_pl>, length_grid1> M1_BETA;` is typically instantiated at the stack, that's too large for the stack available in most environments, yes.

Comment: You should use a `std::vector` for large data.

Comment: It's working with std::vector indeed, thank you! What's the difference with array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `std::vector` as `std::array` is instantiated on the stack. Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array and [std::vector versus std::array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c).