# Using streamsize for the size of an array is not working

Tags: c++, arrays

I somehow can't get it right to use `std::streamsize` to create an array.

```
// determine file size
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
std::streamsize length = file.gcount();
file.clear();
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

// read data into buffer
std::array<char, length> buffer;
file.read(buffer.data(), length);

// copy the game into memory
std::copy(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), memory.begin() + 0x200);
```

Error (translated from German)

> The expression must be a constant value

Does anyone have any ideas on solving this problem? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't use an array, use a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pass constexpr values as template parameters, which clearly isn't possible in this case given that the size is known only at runtime.

The underlying problem here is that you are using the wrong tool for the job: `std::array` encapsulates a statically allocated array, whose size must be known at compile time. If you need dynamic allocation, use `std::vector`.

For a more in-depth comparison between `std::vector` and `std::array` see [std::vector versus std::array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c/4424658#4424658)

Comment: Oh ok then it makes sense not being able to use std::array, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `file.ignore()`, you can use `file.seekg()` to get the file size:

```
// determine file size
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
std::streamsize length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

Or, just use a platform-specific API function, like `GetFileSize()` on Windows or `stat()` on Linux (or equivilents).

That said, `std::array` is a fixed-length array, you have to specify its size at compile-time.  For dynamic allocations at runtime, use `std::vector` instead:

```
// read data into buffer
std::vector<char> buffer;
buffer.resize(length);
file.read(buffer.data(), length);
```

Or, simply read the file into the target memory directly and avoid the temp buffer altogether:

```
// read game file into memory
file.read(memory.begin() + 0x200, length);
```

Or, even skip retrieving the file size at all:

```
// read game file into memory
std::copy(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
    memory.begin() + 0x200
);
```

In any case, be sure to watch out for memory overflows!  Make sure `memory` is large enough to hold the entire `file` data.

Comment: Thanks for the different approaches!
Is there a big difference between the last two? Is one better than the other (e.g. in performance)

Comment: I imagine doing a larger block read will have better performance than doing single-byte reads. But use a profiler to make sure.