# How to pass a const variable in a function?

Tags: c++, constants

It seems parameter passed in functions cannot maintain their const property.
Say that I need to initialize a const variable using information from parameters within a function, then create an array type. How can I do?

example:

```
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void foo(const int info)
{
    const int num = info + 1;  // seems num cannot be constant
    array<int, num> arr;
}
```

compile error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void foo(int)’:
test.cpp:8:16: error: the value of ‘num’ is not usable in a constant expression
 array<int, num> arr;
            ^
test.cpp:7:15: note: ‘num’ was not initialized with a constant expression
     const int num = info + 1;  // seems num cannot be constant
               ^
```

Update：
using array type would cause trouble like that, but using simple type array is just ok：

```
void foo(int info)
{
    int array[info];
}
```

Isn't `info` should be assigned during compile time?

Comment: What is the actual compiler error you're getting? Note that you cannot use a runtime variable as a template parameter argument (`const` is not the same thing as `constexpr`).

Comment: Num needs to be a compile-time constant doesn't it if you want to use it as the size for an array? `const` means it can't be reassigned, not that it's a constant at compile time afaik

Comment: std::array requires a compile-time constant. A function parameter cannot be a compile-time constant. You need std::vector instead.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is a difference between `const` and `constexpr`: [Difference between `constexpr` and `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116003/difference-between-constexpr-and-const)

In your case,  you are trying to create a compile-time sized array, which requires a constexpr.  The constexpr cannot simply be a const variable function argument.  You could use `constexpr` instead, or you could use `vector` (runtime sized array) instead of `array`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I read about constexpr, but still, I cannot understand how to make a function parameter used as constexpr. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @JiangFeng: If you want to make a function parameter be a constexpr,  you can make it a template parameter, as shown by Jeff Garrett's answer here.  You cannot make it a regular argument as you have done.  Most of the time, you should just use `vector` instead of `array` for this sort of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with `gcc -pedantic`, you will see that `int array[info]` is also not standard C++. See [the GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

One way to accomplish the goal of the question is a non-type template parameter:

```
#include <array>

template<int info>
void foo()
{
    constexpr int num = info + 1;
    std::array<int, num> arr; // or int arr[num]
}
// Call as foo<3>()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a dynamically sized array and you don't need the specific properties of std::array, you can just use vector.

Main difference is:

> std::array is a template class that encapsulate a statically-sized
>   array, stored inside the object itself, which means that, if you
>   instantiate the class on the stack, the array itself will be on the
>   stack. Its size has to be known at compile time (it's passed as a
>   template parameter), and it cannot grow or shrink.

Vectors internals, however, are stored on the heap.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424658/128581

Further std::array is trivially copyable (meaning you can memcpy it from one place to another without worrying) if the type T is trivially copyable.

Use vector like:

```
void foo(size_t size)
{
  vector<int> arr(size);
}
```