# Difference between T[N] and std::array<T,N>

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

My question is pretty straightforward, but to be more specific I want to quote 2 lines from [Stroustrup11](http://aksitha.com/Programming/C++/The%20C++%20Programming.Language.4th.Edition.Jun.2013%5BA4%5D.pdf).

1. `T[N]` A fixed-size built-in array: N contiguous elements of type T;
   no `size()` or other member functions
2. `array<T,N>` A fixed-size array of N contiguous elements of type T;
   like the built-in array, but with most problems solved

So what is the difference the author is mentioning? And what problems are solved for `std::array<T,N>` ?

Comment: copy, no decay to `T*`, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The principal differences are that `std::array<T, N>` *doesn't* decay to a pointer to the first element where `T[N]` would, **and** you can take a value copy of a `std::array<T, N>`.

`std::array` also offers some useful functions, such as lexicographical comparison operators.

But because `N` has to be a compile time evaluable constant expression, `std::vector<T>` is often the preferred choice.

Comment: SO [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c/) on this topic.

Comment: @Quentin: Oops. Silly old cat.

Comment: But relation operators are also available `<`, `>`, `<=`, `=>`, `==`, `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike built-in arrays, `std::array` objects can be copied and passed as function parameters.

Overloaded operators and member functions may supply extra debug and runtime checks and eliminate a lot of code duplication. Set of standard members simplifies use of `std::array` objects in generic code.