# Rotate the complete array using rotate function

Tags: c++, algorithm

A array contains element `10,20,30,40,50` 
What i wanna rotate the complete array so as it will `cout` will stream elements `50,40,30,20,10`

I want to solve this problem using rotate function

i tried to write 
    rotate(arr,arr+4,arr+1);

```
  #include<iostream>
  #include<algorithm>
  using namespace std;
  int main()
  {
      int arr[]={10,20,30,40,50};

      rotate(arr,arr+4,arr+1);
      int i;

      for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
      {
       cout<<arr[i]<<"  ";
      }
   }
```

by running above program i getting output `50 10 20 30 40`  which is wrong 
the actual output is  `50 40 30 20 10`

Comment: Because `std::reverse` is too too trivial ?

Comment: You do not want to rotate (this is done correctly, but not what you wanted), you want to mirror/reverse the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you picked the wrong algorithm (quotes from https://en.cppreference.com/w/, emphasis mine):

> Specifically, [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) swaps the elements in the range [first, last) in such a way that **the element n_first becomes the first element of the new range and n_first - 1 becomes the last element**.

What you need is [`std::reverse(first, last)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), which

> **Reverses the order of the elements in the range [first, last)**
>    Behaves as if applying `std::iter_swap` to every pair of iterators first+i, (last-i) - 1 for each non-negative i < (last-first)/2

Comment: thank u so much Bob_ for replying i already referred https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header in which i found using vector.h file Can i write function without vector type

Comment: @AlexStacy Not sure to understand your comment, but you can use either `std::reverse(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));` or `std::reverse(arr, arr + 5);` with your array.

Answer (score 1):

[std::rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/): "Rotates the order of the elements in the range (first,last), in such a way that the element pointed by middle becomes the new first element."

Your std::rotate middle points to "arr+4" i.e. the 5th element: 50.

[image]

You expect "50 40 30 20 10" i.e. to **reverse** the array; not to rotate it. So, you should use [std::reverse](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr { 10,20,30,40,50 };

    std::reverse(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    for (auto i : arr)
        std::cout << i << "  ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u please tell me why did u take std::array<int,5> arr{10,20,30,40,50,}; instead of vector  in more details

Comment: @AlexStacy From [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) reference: "std::array is a container that encapsulates **fixed size arrays**. ... The struct combines the performance and accessibility of a C-style array with the benefits of a standard container, such as knowing its own size, supporting assignment, random access iterators, etc."

Comment: can u please tell me difference between std::array and std::vector

Comment: @AlexStacy , you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea, but I tried to solve this with using rotate()...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v{10,20,30,40,50};
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
    {
       cout<<v[i]<<"  ";
    }
    cout << endl ;

     for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
     {
        rotate(v.rbegin(),v.rbegin()+1,v.rend());
        cout<<v[0]<<"  ";
     }
     cout << endl ;
}
```

g++ rotatev.cpp --std=c++11

```
./a.out
10  20  30  40  50  
50  40  30  20  10
```