# Replace an Integral constant expression as a class template non-type argument by a class member?

Tags: c++, inheritance, non-type-template-parameter

I received a very large code, in which there is a class `template <int dim> class point` which works like a `vector`.

Since that class is involved (in a cascade manner) in many other classes, methods, etc., it forces those other classes, etc., to be templates with the same integral constant expression as a class template non-type argument.
For instance, there is `class D`, to which I want to add:

1. `void D::coords(const point<dim>&)`.
2. `void D::verif(const source<dim>&)`.

Here `source` is a base class (could be abstract), with a huge hierarchy of its own, which uses `point` in one of its methods.
In this case, I guess I am forced to convert `D` and all its derived hierarchy of classes to templates, which means modifying hundreds of sources/headers, at many points.

This addition would be much simpler if `class point` used `dim` as a class member instead of a template argument.
I would simply add the method in `D.h` and `D.cc`.
In all parts of the code that I saw, there is no occasion in which such change would not provide the same functionality.

Before I delve into the attempt to such huge modification, once and for all, I want to know...

**What are possible uses of an integral constant expression as a class template non-type argument that are not replaceable by a class member?**
I guess there should be some, and I welcome all possible examples.
This might help me understanding the options I have (perhaps none!)

Alternatively (option B?),
**Is there a way of making the intended additions, which does not require the huge modifications I foresee, but only the additions in `D.h` and `D.cc`?**

Comment: You can use a specialization of `point` anywhere. Of course if someone wants to pass a specialization with a different template parameter, you're left with no options. Depending on what the `coords` function does you could make only the function a template, but you risk incompatibilities with member variables of course.

Comment: There are some scenarios where the change could actually result in different behavior instead of a compiler error, but those seem far-fetched for a "dimension" parameter. If `class point` is simple enough, you could reduce or eliminate chances of those by declaring all its function members `constexpr`.

Comment: @fabian - You could post your comment as an answer. It might be a suitable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

> *What are possible uses of an integral constant expressions as a class template non-type argument that are not replaceable by a class
> member?*

Any situation where such an expression must be compile-time evaluable. Many examples could be given, but a class with a `std::array` member of 'variant' size is one:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

template<size_t n>
class foo {
public:
    std::array<int, n> data;
    foo() {
        std::fill(data.begin(), data.end(), 42);
    }
    void list()
    {
        for (auto i : data) std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    foo<3> f3; f3.list();
    foo<7> f7; f7.list();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how `foo` could be implemented as a non-template class, even using `constexpr` qualifiers.

In fact, the `std::array` class template *itself* uses a non-type argument that is an "integral constant expression," so that is another example.

Comment: Very good answer. There are uses of `std::array` in the code.
From what I have just quickly checked, all its uses are replaceable by `std::vector` (and proper adjustments) with no big impact in overall performance stemming from what `array` is better than `vector` at.

Comment: ... bearing in mind the differences between `std::array` and `std::vector` (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c), if those are not an issue, your `data` could be changed to `std::vector` and `foo` is not a template anymore.

Comment: Indeed, changing from an `array` to a `vector` would be a potential solution in this case but, as your link points out, that may have undesirable consequences further down the road (such as losing the ability for compile-time evaluation of the size of a class object).

Comment: ... you can add the following line to the end of my `main` for a quick demo: `std::cout << sizeof(f3) << " " << sizeof(f7) << "\n";`