# Initializing an array of vector

Tags: c++, pointers, graph

I am trying to initialize an array of a `vector` of `int`s.

This is my code:

```
vector<int> *vec[] = new vector<int>[n+1];
```

I get the following compilation error:

> initialization with '{...}' expected for aggregate object

What's wrong with this ?

Comment: Why you want to mix and mingle STL containers and raw pointers is beyond me. But you need to remove the `[]` in the declaration. Probably. It's not really clear what you actually want to do.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to initialize an array of pointers to vector with a "pointer to a vector".

Comment: I think you have a bit more of C++ to learn. In current C++ you [don't use new/delete yourself](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly)  (unless you are writing datastructures). If you want n+1 integers all set to 0 use `std::vector<int> values(n+1,0);` [An introduction to std::vector](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/). If you want to allocate memory yourself at least use [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Comment: You may be under the mistaken assumption that `dsa` stands for Data Structures and Algorithms. It doesn't. using the `dsa` tag means you're asking about a public-key cryptographic signature algorithm. Always read the tag information before using a tag.

Comment: `vector<int> *vec[]` is an array of pointers to vectors of int.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<vector<int>[]> vec{std::make_unique<vector<int>[]>(n + 1)};` — but anyway, please don’t do that; just nest it into another `vector`; problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an array (in the broad sense) of elements of type `vector<int>`, I advise you to use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(n+1);
```

`vec` will be a vector of vectors. The number of vectors will be `n+1`  like it seems you wanted. `std::vector` will manage the memory for you, so there's no need for `new`/`delete`.

In C++ we also have [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), but it looks like the number of elements in `vec` is dynamically dependant on `n`, which makes a topmost [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) the proper fit.

There are many advantages using C++ `std::vector`/`std::array` over C style arrays. See e.g. the answers here: [std::vector versus std::array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424579/stdvector-versus-stdarray-in-c).

If you must use a C style topmost array, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you're trying to initialize an array of pointers to vector with a "pointer to a vector".

To **solve** this you can either remove the `[]` from the left hand side of the declaration or not mix `std::vector` and raw pointers.

```
//--------------v----------------------->removed [] from here
vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>[n+1];
```

Comment: While this answers the question it is still not good (maintainable) C++.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Agreed, though I am just highlighting the error meaning to the OP.