# C++ size aware data type/parameter

Tags: c++

I am not sure, but I think I have once seen a method signature that looked like this (in the constructors):

```
class Buffer {
    Buffer(char_with_size *data) { ... };
    Buffer(char *data, size_t len) { ... };
};
```

In the first constructor call an array/pointer parameter can passed of which the compiler automatically knows its size. So, I always know the size of the char buffer passed.

Does anyone know if this really exists in c++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384107/magic-arguments-in-function-templates

Comment: Buffer(std::vector<char>& data);

Answer (score 4):

Only a templated version can possibly make sense:

```
Buffer(char * data, std::size_t len) { /* ... */ }

template <std::size_t N> Buffer(char (&data)[N]) : Buffer(data, N) { }
```

(Note that delegating constructors are new and not very widely supported yet. I just use one here for example's sake.)

Comment: It's not "string length" as much as "array size", really. Only works for arrays, not pointers of course. The template is standard C++; the delegating constructor is standard C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, `Buffer(std::vector<char> data)`. (IOW, don't use `char*`.)