# Why a compiler doesn't deduce the template parameter in case of zero array?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size

I have read the following links how to calculate size of an array through template function:

- [How does this “size of array” template function work?
  [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3368883/2199669)
- [Can someone explain this template code that gives me the size of an
  array? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437150/2199669)
- [Magic arguments in function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2384107/2199669)

  But this trick doesn't work in case of zero array. Why is the following code not correct?
  For instance the online compiler ideone prints the following error message:

> error: no matching function for call to 'size_of_array(int [0])'
>   std::size_t num = size_of_array(arr);

```
#include <cstddef>
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
inline std::size_t size_of_array( T (&)[N] ) {
   return N;
}
int main()
{
  int arr[0]={};
  std::size_t num = size_of_array(arr);
}
```

Comment: zero sized arrays not in a class are illegal.

Comment: @NathanOliver I may be wrong, but iirc 0-sized arrays are only allowed in C for variably sized structs.

Comment: Just replace the initialisation with int arr[]={} or int arr[0];

Comment: Clang++ prints out an explanation: 'candidate template ignored: substitution failure...zero-length arrays are not permitted in C++'.

Comment: @krzaq It may an an extension I have seen.  It is at least illegal in the OP's case.

Answer (score 2):

From the standard draft n4296, §8.3.4 Arrays:

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> D1 [ constant-expression ]
>   attribute-specifier-seq
>
> and the type of the identifier in the
>   declaration T D1 is “derived-declarator-type-list T”, then the type of
>   the identifier of D is an array type;
>
> ...
>
> If the constant-expression is present, it shall be a converted constant expression of type
>   std::size_t and its value shall be greater than zero.

So your code is not valid.

Comment: I suspect the relevant part is the one about type deduction that mentions this one.

Comment: @skypjack yeap, you're right and your answer reflects the essence of the question better, +1 from me. Nevertheless it's worth to mention that the program isn't correct because of zero-sized array usage.

Answer (score 2):

According with [temp.deduct/8] ([working draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#deduct-8), *template argument deduction*, emphasis mine):

> Type deduction may fail for the following reasons:
>   [...]
>   - Attempting to create an array with an element type that is void, a function type, a reference type, or an abstract class type, or **attempting to create an array with a size that is zero** or negative

Type deduction for zero-length arrays may fail (mainly because zero-length arrays are not allowed as well) and that's why you get an error.
Note also that from the same paragraph we have the following (emphasis mine)

> An invalid type or expression is one that would be ill-formed, **with a diagnostic required**, if written using the substituted arguments.

Comment: Thank you. I have checked out this code with gcc for 98, 03, 11, 14 standards. But it did not show the error message about of definition of a zero sized array. So gcc does not implement this feature.

Comment: @mhd I didn't get your comment, sorry. What feature GCC doesn't implement? You got an error out of your code and I've given you an idea about the reason.

Comment: In my comment above I meant the zero sized array which is a not correct code. I compiled this code `int main(){int arr[0]={};}` with gcc v6.2.1 with following options:  -std=c++98;  -std=c++03;  -std=c++11;  -std=c++14;  But gcc didn't print an error message about the zero sized array.

Comment: @mhd Use option `-pedantic`. It compiles because of a compiler extension, but with that option it warns you saying that it's not valid code.