# Pass arrays to a function. What is the difference between arguments int *ptr vs int ptr[ ]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

What is the difference between the below codes when passing the array to the function? Which should be used when writing a code?

PS: I would like to know the difference in using int *ptr vs int ptr[] in the function argument.

```
void foo(int *ptr)
{
    ...
    ...
}

void main()
{
   int a[]={10,20,30};
   foo(a);
   
}
```

vs

```
void foo(int ptr[])
{
    ...
    ...
}

void main()
{
   int a[]={10,20,30};
   foo(a);
   
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no difference. For function parameters, arrays decay to pointers. You don't get a copy of the array but only the address of first element. Also you cannot take the size of the parameter as it will only be size of a pointer.

Comment: There is no difference, and any competent C engineer will see/know them as synonymous. The "which should be used", therefore, becomes at-best pure opinion, and essentially irrelevant.

Comment: And, in _both_ functions, you can use either `*(ptr + 2)` or `ptr[2]` [preferred]. Also `++ptr` (which you can _not_ do in `main`)

Comment: Not an exact dupe but the answers apply for you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975128/why-isnt-the-size-of-an-array-parameter-the-same-as-within-main

Comment: It should be noted (because “C/C++” exists in people’s minds) that it gets trickier in C++ — you can pass a _reference_ to an array in C++, which preserves array size information. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/when-a-function-has-a-specific-size-array-parameter-why-is-it-replaced-with-a-p and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384107/how-does-this-template-magic-determine-array-parameter-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array to pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Array_to_pointer_conversion)

> When an array type is used in a function parameter list, it is transformed to the corresponding pointer type:
>
> `int f(int a[2])` and `int f(int* a)` declare the same function.
>
> Since the function's actual parameter type is pointer type, a function call with an array argument performs array-to-pointer conversion; ...

Answer (score 2):

They're exactly the same.

If a parameter to a function is declared to have array type, that parameter is adjusted to pointer type.

This is spelled out in section 6.7.6.3p7 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Function Declarators:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
> ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
> those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If
> the keyword static also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type
> derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
> corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
> element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
> size expression.

This is in part due to the fact that in most contexts an array decays to a pointer to its first element, so it's not even possible to pass an array to a function (although you can pass a pointer to an array).

From a readability standpoint, you might want to use the array syntax when you expect to receive a pointer to the first element of the array, while you might want to use the pointer syntax when you expect to receive a pointer to a single object.

For example:

```
void foo1(int *p)
{
    *p += 2;
}

void foo2(int p[], int len)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", p[i]);
    }
}
```

You can use either syntax in both cases, but the particular syntax makes it more apparent what the function is operating on.