# Segmentation fault while running bubble sort

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, bubble-sort

I am trying to run a bubble sort algorithm which sorts an array in an ascending order but it comes out with segmentation fault in the online compiler and I can't figure out what's going wrong in there because I think that an element in an array should have a size of four, but after I try I couldn't find the solution. Can someone help me to have a look?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void bubble_sort(int arr[]);
void printArray(int arr[]);

int main()
{

    int arr[] = {10, 4, 2, 8, 11, 15};

    bubble_sort(arr);
    printArray(arr);
    // cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;

    return 0;
}


void bubble_sort(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < ((sizeof(arr) / 4) - 1); j++)
        {
            int temp;
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr) / 4); i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: When declared as an argument, `int arr[]` is parsed by the compiler as `int *arr`. All you have is a pointer, and the size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself not what it points to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate Length of Array in C by Using Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162923/calculate-length-of-array-in-c-by-using-function)

Comment: And don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If the division by `4` is meant to be the size of `int` then use `sizeof(int)` instead. There's no guarantee by the C++ language specification that `sizeof(int)` must be equal to `4`.

Comment: And finally how to solve your problem the C++ way: Use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for your array instead, and pass a reference to it to the functions.

Comment: Oh and the loop `for (int j = 0; i < ((sizeof(arr) / 4) - 1); j++)` doesn't make sense in multiple ways.

Answer (score 0):

The nested for loop in the bubble_sort has a terminating condition of `i < ((sizeof(arr) / 4) - 1)`. Because the variable `i` is never incremented in the nested loop, it will loop forever. Try `j < ((sizeof(arr) / 4) - 1)` instead. This is what causes your segmentation fault.

I'd also recommend taking the size of your array and passing it to your functions as a separate parameter, rather than trying to use `sizeof` from within the function. As mentioned by 'Some programmer dude', the `sizeof` function is currently using the size of an `*int`, not the number of elements in your array. `sizeof(arr)` in your `main` function would resolve this.

(This is my first answer on Stack Overflow so forgive me for any formatting errors.)

Comment: I do not really agree with passing the size as a seperate argument. In practice this means that the size of the array and the value of the size may (due to programming errors) start to differ at runtime. So either use std::array or make function templates that fix in the size of the array at compile time. (If size of the array can vary at runtime, use std::vector and then size/allocated memory are still self contained within one instance of std::vector)

Comment: @PepijnKramer you make a good point. I had not considered array size differential at runtime. I had also never seen the "int(&arr)[N]" syntax you submitted in your answer. I will need to learn to incorporate this into my programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to deal with arrays in C++ e.g.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// 
// using namespace std; <== unlearn to do this. 
//

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Instead of having to do sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) and trying to deal with pointer decay/losing size informatino of the array : 
// Use this syntax int (&arr)[N] to pass an array by reference AND its size N
// (or use std::array<int,N>&)
// I made this a function template so the function will compile for any N
// I also replaced int by std::size_t since that's the common indexing type 
// in collections (and unlike int it cant get to negative indices)

template<std::size_t N>
void bubble_sort(int(&arr)[N])
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) // no need to divide by sizeof(int)
    {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < N - 1; j++) // <== you had an i here in the comparison in your original code, also a bug
        {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                std::swap(arr[j], arr[j + 1]); // using swap make code explain itself
            }
        }
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

template<std::size_t N>
void printArray(const int(&arr)[N])     // pass by const content off arr must not be modifiable by print
{
    bool comma = false;
    std::cout << "[";

    // use range based for loop, can't go out of bound.
    for (const auto value : arr)
    {
        if (comma) std::cout << ",";
        std::cout << value;
        comma = true;
    }

    std::cout << "]\n"; // preferably don't use std::endl (it will flush and slow output down)
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    int arr[]{ 10, 4, 2, 8, 11, 15 };

    bubble_sort(arr);
    printArray(arr);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern C++ way to bubble sort:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>

template <std::ranges::bidirectional_range R>
void bubble_sort(R&& r) {
  while (true) {
      auto it = std::ranges::is_sorted_until(r);
      if (it == std::end(r)) {
          break;
      }
      std::iter_swap(it, std::prev(it));
  }
}

template <std::ranges::forward_range R>
void print(R&& r) {
    for (auto it = std::begin(r); it != std::end(r); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {10, 4, 2, 8, 11, 15};

    bubble_sort(arr);
    print(arr);
}
```

Demo : https://wandbox.org/permlink/Co4k1GA8ozQ9PfDv

Note that:

- You don't need to know the size of array here
- The algorithm isn't restricted to C-style arrays, you can use (doubly) linked lists, vectors, spans, binary trees, or whatever
- The code is much more "descriptive"; you find "where is sorted until", ans "stops if the spot is the end of the range", and if not, "swaps with content at right before that spot"

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code.

1. In the main() function where you declare **int arr[]**, you can get the correct size of the array as follow:

   **int array_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);**
2. However, outside the main() function, and inside the 2 functions **bubble_sort(arr[])** and **printArray(int arr[])**, you will get the wrong size of the array with the code:

   **int array_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);**

   because these 2 functions only sees the input parameter **int arr[]** as a pointer to int.
3. But, the main reason your code crashes is as follow.  In the bubble_sort() function, your second **for** loop is incorrect and should have been written as follow:

   **for (int j = 0; j < (size - i - 1); j++)**

====================================

So, I make some small modifications to your original code, and it works as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

void bubble_sort(int arr[], int size);
void printArray(int arr[], int size);

int main()
{

    int arr[] = {10, 4, 2, 8, 11, 15};

    int array_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    bubble_sort(arr, array_size);
    printArray(arr, array_size);
    // cout<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;

    return 0;
}


void bubble_sort(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j  < size - i - 1; j++)
        {
            int temp;
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

==================

Note: My answer is very similar to what other people have commented before (such as user "Caden Kroonenberg", and "Some programmer dude"). I only want to write the whole correct code for readability and for my own references as well :-).

Comment: may I know that is there a way that I do not need to pass the size of an array as argument, which is like I just pass the array and the function itself will help me calculate the size of my array but in a similar way to my original function?

Comment: @LimChinHong No, there is no way to calculate the size of the "array".  It has decayed to a pointer, thus all of the size information is gone.

Comment: @LimChinHong,  User "PaulMcKenzie" is right. Unfortunately, there is no way to do exactly what you ask for because this is how C++ works.  However, other users wrote some great answers below that use very ADVANCED C++ skills, which do not require the code to know the size of the array at all.