# Understanding the information lost while passing array to a function without its size 

Tags: c++, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding size of int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037736/finding-size-of-int-array)

I am curious why I get the following behaviour in this simple C++ code.

In this I try to calculate the size of a float array in 2 different places:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

void foo(float a[])
{
 int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(float) ;

 cout << size <<std::endl;   
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  float a[] = {22.2, 44.4, 66.6} ;

  int size = sizeof(a) / sizeof(float) ;

  cout << size <<std::endl;   

  foo(a);

  return 0;
}
```

Using the `gcc` compiler I get the output as

```
~: ./a.out
3
2
~:
```

With other array sizes I get the first entry to be the correct size but the second always  to be 2,

Now in my codes I never pass arrays without their sizes if I use arrays and I usually use the std:: vectors. But I am curious what is happening here.

What information has the 'a' lost while being passed to the function?

What is the second sizeof(a) calculating ?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Comment: On MSVC 2010, I get 3 and 1.  Intriguing.

Comment: @Joe: 32bit and 64bit pointers. 4byte(32bit pointer) / 4byte(float) == 1, 8byte(64bit pointer) / 4byte(float) == 2.

Comment: @xeo I had just realized the array decayed to a pointer and came to find your comment :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second sizeof() is calculating: `sizeof(float*) / sizeof(float)`. The parameter of function `foo` is just a pointer to the first member of the array, it's similar (**EDIT: identical**) to `float*`. So sizeof(array) will give you the size of the pointer pointing to the first member, no matter if the array is int[], float[] or char[].

Comment: It's not only "similar to `float*`", it's exactly the same in a function parameter. :)

Comment: +1 You beat me to it by a fraction of a second :D Are there any practical differences between the passed float[] and a float* ?

Comment: @daramarak: When encountered in a function parameter, *no*. They are exactly the same.

Comment: I think it was a big mistake in C to disallow real array function parameters (an array return values), and even worse that when they disallowed it they just repurposed array syntax rather than making it an error.

Answer (score 0):

Having tested it [here](http://ideone.com/DsnT6), you see that the second result is 1.  I suspect (not entirely sure) that your foo argument has pointer decay going on, so it calculates the `sizeof(float*)` instead of just a `float`

Comment: `float a[]` is the same as `float* a` in a function parameter.