# C C++ array.... need help understanding code

Tags: c++, loops

Can you please explain this code? It seems a little confusing to me
Is "a" a double array? I would think it's just an integer, but then in the cout statement it's used as a double array. Also in the for loop condition it says a<3[b]/3-3, it makes no sense to me, however the code compiles and runs. i'm just having trouble understanding it, it seems syntactically incorrect to me

```
int a,b[]={3,6,5,24};
char c[]="This code is really easy?";
for(a=0;a<3[b]/3-3;a++)
{
cout<<a[b][c];
}
```

Comment: Whomever wrote that code should be fired...  This is exactly what not to do when you write code.

Comment: @Reed: I suspect that it is bad on purpose. Looks like an assignment to test the students ability to wade through syntax...

Comment: That being said, it also, technically, buggy, since it's going to access b[4], (since a iterates while <5) which doesn't exist.

Comment: This clearly is not C, unless there is a `cout` integer defined somewhere outside this code.

Comment: @dreamlax: obligatory quote: "I saw `cout’ being shifted “Hello world” times to the left and stopped right there."

Comment: @Alok: That's awesome, where is that quote from?

Comment: @dreamlax: I remember reading it long ago in a Linux fortune command's output I think, and then googled it after reading your comment.  It is widely attributed to one Steve Gonedes, but I am not sure if the attribution is correct. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879034/what-is-the-zen-of-c/1879046#1879046 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wow.  This is really funky.  This isn't really 2 dimensional array. it works because `c` is an array and there is an identity in the C language that treats this

```
b[3]
```

as the same as this

```
3[b]
```

so this code translates into a loop that increments a while `a < (24/3-3)` since `3[b]` is the same as `b[3]` and b[3] is 24.  Then it uses `a[b]` (which is the same as `b[a]`) as an index into the array c.

so, un-obfuscated this code is

```
int a;
int b[] = {3,5,6,24}
char c[] = "This code is really easy?";
for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
{
    cout << c[b[a]];
}
```

which is broken since b[4] doesn't exist, so the output should be the 3rd, 5th, 6th and 24th characters of the string c or

```
sco?
```

followed by some random character or a crash.

Comment: I see. I didn't know 3[b] was the same as b[3]... okay I get how it works now.  Thanks a lot all.

Comment: in other words, array subscripting is commutative in C.  Note that this is not the case in all variants of C++ (Visual C++, for instance).

Answer (score 7):

Array accessors are almost syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. `a[b]` is equivalent to `b[a]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`.

That said, using `index[array]` rather than `array[index]` is utterly horrible and you should never use it.

Comment: I think this is the first time I've ever seen anyone say WHY a[b] and b[a] are equivalent... it seems blaringly obvious now that it's pointed out, but seeing it written as *(a+b) made that syntax finally clear after years of C coding.

Comment: @Tanzelax - that equivalence is pointed out in many C texts (and should be in any good one).  It's the definition of the '[]' operator. It's in both Harbison & Steele and in the C standard (which along with Plauger's "Standard C Library" are pretty much the only C texts I refer to anymore - C++ still requires a slew of texts unfortunately).

Comment: @Anon: there's one time when I use the `index[array]` form - in a macro for getting the number of elements in an array.  Using the `index[array]` form prevents the expression from working accidentally for a C++ class that overloads the '`[]`' operator (admittedly, it's a very specialized use).

Comment: That helps e.g. in array-size macros, see e.g. this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array/1598827#1598827

Comment: @Michael: Yeah, I've seen it separately that a[b] = *(a+b) (as you said, it's in just about every C text), and that a[b] = b[a], but for some reason the two bits just never connected.

Comment: @Tanzelax: I see - I'd agree that those dots aren't always connected explicitly, and that the connection might not be something that jumps out.

Comment: @Michael: Funny, i only now noticed that the linked answer was from you - otherwise i would have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

No, two variables are declared in the first statement: `int a` and `int b[]`.

`a[b][c]` is just a tricky way of saying `c[b[a]]`, that is because of the syntax for arrays: `b[0]` and `0[b]` are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a,b[]={3,6,5,24};
```

Declares two variables, an int a and an array of ints b

```
char c[]="This code is really easy?";
```

Declares an array of char with the given string

```
for(a=0;a<3[b]/3-3;a++)
```

Iterates a through the range [0..4]:

- 3[b] is another way of saying b[3], which is 24.
- 24 / 3 = 8
- 8 - 3 = 5

```
cout << a[b][c];
```

This outputs the following result:

- a[b] is equivalent to b[a], which will be b[0..4]
- b[0..4][c] is another way of saying c[b[0..4]]

Comment: It's not c[0..4], it should be c[b[0..4]]

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a simple trick in the code. `a[3]` is exactly the same as `3[a]` for c compiler.

After knowing this your code can be transformed into more meaningful:

```
int a,b[]={3,6,5,24};
char c[]="This code is really easy?";
for(a=0;a<b[3]/3-3;a++)
{
cout<<c[b[a]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a<3[b]/3-3 is the same as writing

a < b[3]/3-3

and a[b] is the same is b[a] since a is an integer
sp b[a] is one of the items from {3,6,5,24}

which then means a[b][c] is b[a][c]
which is either c[{3,6,5,24}]

Answer (score 0):

foo[bar] "expands" to "*(foo + bar)" in C. So `a[b]` is actually the same as `b[a]` (because addition is commutative), meaning the ath element of the array b. And `a[b][c]` is the same as `c[b[a]]` i.e. the ith char in c where i is the ath element in b.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - first, let's tackle the for loop.

When you write `b[3]`, this is equivelent to `*(b+3)`.  `*(b+3)` is also equivelent to `*(3+b)`, which can be written as `3[b]`.  This basically can be rewritten, more understandably, as:

```
for(a=0; a < ((b[3]/3) - 3); a++)
```

Since b[3] is a constant value (24), you can see this as:

```
for(a=0; a < ((24/3) - 3); a++)
```

or

```
for(a=0; a < (8 - 3); a++)
```

and finally:

```
for(a=0; a < 5; a++)
```

In your case, this will make `a` iterate from 0-4.  You then output `a[b][c]`, which can be rewritten as c[b[a]].

However, I don't see how this compiles and runs correctly, since it's accessing `c[b[4]]` - and b only has 4 elements.  This, as written, is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

First: 'a' is not initialized. Let's assume that it is initialized to 0.

'3[b]/3-3' equals 5. The loop will go from 0 to 4 using 'a'. ('3[b]' is 'b[3]')

In the a==4 step 'a[b]' (so 'b[a]') will be out of bounds (bounds of 'b' is 0..3) so it has undefined behavior. On my computer somethimes 'Segmentation fault' sometimes not. Until that point it outputs: "soc?"

Comment: My bad. I used to declare and initialize loop variables inplace or as late as it is possible so it missed my mind. :-)