# How to determine the length of an array at compile time?

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, compile-time

Are there macros or builtins that can return the length of arrays at compile time in GCC?

For example:

```
int array[10];
```

For which:

```
sizeof(array) == 40
???(array) == 10
```

### Update0

I might just point out that doing this in C++ is trivial. One can build a template that returns the number inside `[]`. I was certain that I'd once found a `lengthof` and `dimof` macro/builtin in the Visual C++ compiler but cannot find it anymore.

Comment: See also SO question: [Is there a standard function in C that would return the length of an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))
```

Or as a macro

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(foo) (sizeof(foo)/sizeof(foo[0]))

    int array[10];
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(array), ARRAY_SIZE(array));

40 10
```

Caution: You can apply this `ARRAY_SIZE()` macro to a pointer to an array and get a garbage value without any compiler warnings or errors.

Comment: Well, there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of competition for this one!

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't rely on sizeof since aligment stuff could mess up the thing.

```
#define COUNT 10
int array[COUNT];
```

And then you could use COUNT as you want.

Comment: isn't alignment just important for placing the array itself? Inside a c-array, the sizeof-division shall work.

Comment: I think you're right: both sizeof will take alignment into consideration. So the sizeof(blah)/sizeof(type) should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
    sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

im not aware of a builtin that does this, but i recently used:

> sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])

to do just that