# How to find the size of any array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I want to find the size of any array type. My code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename t>
int some_function(t arr []){
    int s;
    s = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(t);
    return s;
}

int main(){
    int arr1 [] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    char arr2 [] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    int size;
    size = some_function(arr1);
    cout << "Size of arr1 : "<<size<<endl;
    size = some_function(arr2);
    cout << "Size of arr2 : "<<size<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code on cpp.sh output is:

```
Size of arr1 : 2
Size of arr2 : 8
```

and when I run it on CodeBlocks and Visual Studio output is:

```
Size of arr1 : 1
Size of arr2 : 4
```

I want it to print the exact size of an array which is:

```
Size of arr1 : 8
Size of arr2 : 5
```

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution with the help of [rsp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6935629/rsp) and [Cheersandhth.-Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf). I was passing the array by value which is implicitly converted to pointer. After reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) and answer provided by **rsp** I passed the array by reference. So final code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename t, int s>
int some_function(t (&arr)[s]){
    return s;
}

int main(){
    int arr1 [] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    char arr2 [] = {'a','b','c','d','e'};
    int size;
    size = some_function(arr1);
    cout << "Size of arr1 : "<<size<<endl;
    size = some_function(arr2);
    cout << "Size of arr2 : "<<size<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you everyone for help...

Comment: Why not use `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: `arr` is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Closed as FAQ. [[[

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: Hey, who removed my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43444235/c-does-gcc-provide-extended-macro-function-like-countof-the-size-of-an-arra link?

Comment: @melpomene: I did. It appeared to be about compiler-specific functionality, which would be entirely wrong as an answer to this question. It's a FAQ.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Well, the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43444328/4944425) to that question is not compiler specific.

Comment: @Bob__: Right, I see. It would be nice with some other reference to C++ `std::size`, because I don't think that's in the (old) FAQ. The linked answer suffers from appearing to be about gcc functionality, and does not mention the limitation discussed in the FAQ for a Do It Yourself `constexpr` `size`, inability to find size of array by reference, which unfortunately still applies to `std::size` (it's not been fixed).  I think a question purely about `std::size`  could be nice along with the FAQ ref. Or better, if Someone™ updated that FAQ. :)

Comment: It isn't really to do with *passing an array by value*, because that doesn't exist in C++. What happens is that a function parameter `T t[N]` gets adjusted to `T* t`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called arrays decaying into pointers. When you pass an array by value they decay into a pointer. So, the size of the array is nothing but the size of a pointer which is depends on the system.

Comment: So how can I find the size of an array, without passing the size explicitly

Comment: @MAY - Please read my comment above

Comment: @MAY One way is to use a sentinel value like the `'\0'` character used to terminate c-style strings.

Comment: @EdHeal Thanks for suggesting that, but what if I don't want to use vector or array container

Comment: @may: You can just read the FAQ linked as a duplicate.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I am reading that, thanks

Comment: Thanks to everyone for help and especially **rsp** and @Cheersandhth.-Alf. I am passing the array by value which is converted into pointer implicitly so I passed it by reference.
`template <typename t, int N>`
`int some_function(t (&arr)[N]){`
`return N;`
`}`

Comment: What really happens is that `t arr []` is *type adjusted* to `t* arr`. Where array decaying comes in is that it allows passing an array to the function to compile. But the function parameter is always a pointer.

Answer (score -4):

While calling your function try adding  datatype of your array

```
size = some_function<int>(arr1);

size = some_function<char>(arr2);
```