# Is there any shortcut for array size / length in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any way to speed up getting an array size in C?

Typing out `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)` every time gets old.  Do any C libraries have something like `.length` or is there some way I can define `sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)` as a shorter constant of some sort (possible also using dot notation)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standard function in C that would return the length of an array? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array)

Comment: C's treatment of arrays is the source of a lot of heartburn.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` and make a macro.

```
#define length(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*(array)))
```

Comment: @typoknig `*array` is the same as `array[0]`

Answer (score 12):

All solutions in C boil down to a macro:

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array)[0]))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could always just write a macro to do it. Note that it won't work as a function, since you'd have to demote the array to a pointer to its first element, so it'd just return `sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int)`.

```
#define INTSIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / (sizeof(int))
```

Or, more generally...

```
#define SIZE(array, type) (sizeof(array) / (sizeof(type))
```

Wow, downvotes. Okay, this will also work:

```
#define SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / (sizeof((array)[0]))
```

Comment: To expand on Let_Me_Be's comment, you can write `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` and not worry about type *at all* (although in the context of a macro it may be safer to write it as `(sizeof (arr) / sizeof *(arr)`).

Comment: Actually using a separate type is kind of dangerous, but I have removed the downvote, since you edited the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is "no"; in C, there is no way to get the number of elements in an array *based on the array expression alone*.  The `sizeof` trick is about as good as it gets, and its use is limited to expressions of array type.  So the following won't work:

```
char *foo = malloc(1024);
size_t count = sizeof foo;
```

`count` receives the number of bytes for the pointer type (4 on a typical desktop architecture), not in the allocated block.

```
char arr[100];
char *p = arr;
size_t count = sizeof p;
```

Same as above.

```
void foo(char *arr)
{
  size_t count = sizeof arr; // same as above
  ...
}

void bar(void)
{
  char array[100];
  foo(array);
  ... 
}
```

Same as above.

If you need to know how many elements are in an array, you need to track that information separately.

C's treatment of arrays is the source of a *lot* of heartburn.