# Common array length macro for C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, c-preprocessor

I've seen several macros for array length floating around:

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307929/is-there-any-shortcut-for-array-size-length-in-c):

- `#define length(array) (sizeof(array)/sizeof(*(array)))`
- `#define ARRAY_LENGTH(array) (sizeof((array))/sizeof((array)[0]))`
- `#define SIZE(array, type) (sizeof(array) / (sizeof(type))`

And Visual Studio's [`_countof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773(v=VS.100).aspx):

```
#define _countof(_Array) (sizeof(_Array) / sizeof(_Array[0]))
```

What I'd like to know is:

1. What's the difference between those using `array[0]` and `*array`?
2. Why should either be preferred?
3. Do they differ in C++?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here's a better C version (from Google's Chromium project):

```
#define COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))
```

It improves on the `array[0]` or `*array` version by using `0[array]`, which is equivalent to `array[0]` on plain arrays, but will fail to compile if `array` happens to be a C++ type that overloads `operator[]()`.

The division causes a divide-by-zero operation (that should be caught at compile time since it's a compile-time constant expression) for many (but not all) situations where a pointer is passed as the `array` parameter.

See [Is there a standard function in C that would return the length of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array/1598827#1598827) for more details.

There's a better option for C++ code.  See [Compile time sizeof_array without using a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500363/compile-time-sizeofarray-without-using-a-macro/1500917#1500917) for details.

Comment: That's incredibly cryptic just to guard against being used wrongly in C++, considering that something else should be used in C++ anyway.

Comment: You're right that this shouldn't be used in C++, but the bit that provides some safety specifically for C++ isn't really too cryptic (it's just the unusual indexing). The really cryptic part guards against some types of misuse in C that is actually pretty hard to guard against (and the macro doesn't even perfect guard against this misuse). The misuse it guards against (passing a pointer instead of an array argument) occurs often enough that it pays to have the complexity. Wrapped up in a macro, the complexity isn't too much of an issue (and this macro is less cryptic than many I come across).

Comment: What the hell type is `0[x]`? You can do that?

Comment: @Matt: the `[]` operator is commutative (by virtue of it being defined in terms of pointer arithmetic).  However that part of the macro is the less important 'safety' - I'm sorry that it seems to be getting the attention.

Comment: As noted in the linked source , the second half of this check only catches some cases. (In particular it doesn't catch `x` being a `char *`, which is a common use case)

Comment: Since there is a better option for C++ code, that should probably be used: `#ifdef __cplusplus ... version for C++ .... #else ... version for C ... #endif`

Comment: How you can tell that it is better **C** version if you are talking about overloading `operator[]()`?

Answer (score 18):

1. What's the difference between those using array[0] and *array?
2. Why should either be preferred?
3. Do they differ in C++?

(1) No difference in C. No difference for an actual raw array in C++.

(2) No technical grounds to prefer one or the other, but newbies might be confused by the pointer dereference.

(3) In C++ you would normally not use the macro, because it's very unsafe. If you pass in a pointer instead of an actual raw array, code will compile but yield incorrect result. So in C++ you would/should instead use a function template, like …

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef ptrdiff_t Size;

template< class Type, Size n >
Size countOf( Type (&)[n] ) { return n; }
```

This only accepts actual raw array as argument.

It's part of a triad of functions `startOf`, `endOf` and `countOf` that it's very convenient to define so that they can be applied to both raw arrays and standard library containers. As far as I know this triad was first identified by Dietmar Kuehl. In C++0x `startOf` and `endOf` will most probably be available as `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: +1: Interesting!  Is there a reason to use `<stddef.h>` rather than `<cstddef>`?

Comment: Not that I can think of; and I can think of several reasons to prefer <cstddef>.

Comment: For what little it's worth, here's my take on the `<cstddef>` vs. `<stddef.h>` reasoning (note: I prefer the old-fashioned C variation myself): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118422/scope-of-c-libraries-in-c-x-h-vs-cx/2118718#2118718

Comment: I'm in the `stddef.h` even in C++ camp too. Trying to deprecate C standard library is ridiculous.

Comment: Worth noting that in general there is a difference between `*a` and `a[0]`, which shows up when `a` is a pointer to an incomplete type. This doesn't influence the `sizeof` though, since in that case `sizeof` would be invalid anyway.

Comment: template countOf does not work if array is a member of a class.
To make it working with class members, it should be extended with another template parameter

    `template<class C, class T, size_t N>`
    `static inline constexpr size_t countOf(T (C::*)[N]) { return N; }`

Comment: @hutorny: There is a case where the function template doesn't work as a given, but that problematic case is not for member of a class, and it's not for current standard C++. If you want to use it for an array  type where you don't have an instance, whether in a class or not, then you can either pass it a pseudo-instance via e.g. `std::declval`, or you can use the standard library's array type dimension thing (I forget the name, sorry, I've never needed it).

Answer (score 4):

1) Nothing, the value of an array is a pointer to it's first element. So *array == array[0]
2) Personal Preference
3) No

Note that this macro wont work if called inside a function where the array is passed as a parameter into the function. This is because the array object passed "decays" into a pointer rather than a deep copy.

Comment: Yes, it may effectively work as `sizeof(void*)/sizeof(array[0])`, which - in contemporary reality - means 8, 4, 2, 1, or 0. ;) Anyway - nothing can help you in such a function at compile time - you can never know who calls it, and with how large an array.