# What is going wrong with the logic?

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, number-theory

I'm trying to write a prime generator that implements the sieve of Eratosthenes. However, it includes some composite numbers (such as 25, 49 and other multiples of 5 and 7) in the output.

Here's my code:

```
/*****
 * To find out prime numbers from 1 to 100 with a different procedure
 * Author:Udit Gupta
 * Date:20/08/2011
 */

#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a[100],i,j,k,n;

    for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
        a[i] = i+1;  /*1 to 100 numbers are entered into array*/

    /*Here te actual logic starts .......*/
    j = 1;
    while ( (a[j] != 0) && (j!=50) ) {
        k = 1;
        n = a[j];

        while( (n * k) < 99) {
            a[j+(n*k)] = 0;
            k++;
        }

        j++;
    }

    /*To print output of the array*/
    for (i=0;i<=99;i++) {
        if ( a[i] != 0)
            printf("\n%d",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output ....

> ```
>     
> udit@udit-Dabba ~/Desktop/letusc/ch8 $ gcc -o Dd Dd.c -Wall
> udit@udit-Dabba ~/Desktop/letusc/ch8 $ ./Dd
> ```

1
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
25
29
31
35
37
41
43
47
49
53
55
59
61
65
67
71
73
77
79
83
85
89
91
95
97

Comment: 1 isn't a prime number, by the way...

Comment: have you tried using a debugger

Comment: Why don't you try debugging your code to find out?

Comment: @MByD: I think the problem is 1, 25, 35, 49, 55, 65, 77, 85, 91 and 95.

Comment: @omri yes you are right... I have applied the logic acc. to what I thought is right if somebody could tell me what's wrong I have done ?????

Comment: Never mind the debugger if you're not familiar with it - just add printf's to show the values j,n, and the values being set to zero...

Comment: @DNA: that also has the advantage that you can see the relevant values all at once, instead of having to step many loops. <g>

Comment: @DNA: this is the perfect time to learn interactive debugging. A short program, a simple yet subtle bug. There's a time for scaffolding, but this isn't it.

Comment: @Udit: off topic, you can shorten the number of iterations of the outer loop by changing the upper bound from 50 to something much lower. See if you can figure out what and why (hint: 100 = 2 * 50 = 5 * 20 = 10 * 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st hint: in a debugger, break on the `n = a[j];` line. Run a few iterations. Does it ever stop when `a[j]` == 5?

> ```
> udit@udit-Dabba ~/Desktop/letusc/ch8 $ gdb ./Dd
> [GDB preamble elided]
> (gdb) b main
> Breakpoint 1 at 0x100000e63: file Dd.c, line 12.
> (gdb) r
> Starting program: /home/udit/Desktop/letusc/ch8/Dd
> Reading symbols for shared libraries +. done
>
> Breakpoint 1, main () at Dd.c:12
> 12      for(i=0;i<=99;i++)
> (gdb) watch n
> Hardware watchpoint 2: n
> (gdb) c
> Continuing.
> Hardware watchpoint 2: n
>
> Old value = 0
> New value = 2
> main () at Dd.c:21
> 21          while( (n * k) < 99) {
> (gdb) c
> Continuing.
> Hardware watchpoint 2: n
>
> Old value = 2
> New value = 3
> main () at Dd.c:21
> 21          while( (n * k) < 99) {
> (gdb) p j
> $1 = 2
> (gdb)
> ```

RMS's (no relation to *that* [RMS](http://stallman.org/)) [GDB tutorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbtoc.html) includes a section on [watchpoints](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbwatch.html), which the sample session above makes use of.

More hints to follow, as you need them.

Comment: I am very new to programming and linux also pleas help me out how to debug the code on linux machine ??

Comment: A guide would be best. Try [Linux software debugging with GDB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gdb/), or search the web if that doesn't work for you. Short version: `gdb *executable*` to start gdb, `b (*function name*|*line number*)` to set a breakpoint, `r` to start the program running, `c` to continue after a breakpoint (until the next breakpoint), `p *expr*` to print the value of an expression (such as a variable name), `s` to step through a line. See [GDB Cheat Sheet](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html) for more info on commands.

Comment: It never reaches n = 5. It stops far too early.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I will try to work on debugging and got clear here...Its never executing for n=5

Answer (score 1):

```
while (n * k < 99) {
  a[j + n * k] = 0;
  k++;
}
```

This code is dangerous. You may well end up with `j + n * k` being larger than 99, which will overwrite arbitrary memory (or, strictly speaking, the *behavior is undefined*). Better be safe:

```
#include <assert.h>

...

while (n * k < 99) {
  int index = j + n * k;
  assert(0 <= index && index < 100);
  a[index] = 0;
  k++;
}
```

Comment: An index of < 0 is rather unlikely, isn't it?

Comment: Alternatively (or additionally), change the condition to check that the index is in range: `while (j + n * k < LENGTH(a))`, given a suitable definition for [`LENGTH`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415524/common-array-length-macro-for-c).

Comment: @Rudy: asserts often test "impossible" scenarios, just in case.

Comment: @outis: Hey, that's what Udit should find out himself. ;)

Comment: @Roland: He wouldn't have found out, because *that* is not the problem with his loop.

Comment: @outis: it is impossible though, so really no need to test for it, IMO.

Comment: @Rudy: I probably wouldn't have tested it myself, but that's more out of my own bad habits than the mathematical impossibility.

Comment: @outis: OK. The test won't hurt anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, do yourself a favor and do a web search on "tutorial on gdb debugger". You'll get hundreds of hits. Then, sit down and have some fun learning a powerful tool that you will spend hundreds and hundreds of hours using if you continue to learn C, C++, or a dozen other computer languages. (I'm serious about the 'fun' part; I you don't find it fun, drop CS!)

Also do a search on 'ddd debugger'; this is a free OSS graphical front-end to gdb -- very nice, IMHO.

-k

Comment: Indeed, running code line-by-line in gdb *is* fun. Often the problem line (or transition between lines) can just "jump out" at you. You may not instantly know what's wrong and how to fix it; but you can "sense" that something fishy just happened. Knowing *where* it's going wrong makes it easy to begin investigating *why*.

Answer (score 0):

hint ; look at what happened to 5 and hence 25

google will tell you how to use gdb - its not hard

```
a[j + n * k] = 0;
```

I think you mean

```
a[n * k] = 0;
```

Comment: `j=4 so n=a[4]=5 and then for j=4,4+5*1,4+5*2,etc it will go and        will make them zero. 25 is a[24] and 24 = 4+5*4`

Comment: @Udit: Try to observe that happening in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing your results (marking non-primes as zero) in the same array as you are reading from within the outer loop.

The number 4 gets (correctly) marked as non-prime, but this has the unwanted side-effect of terminiating your main loop (because a[j] ==0).

So you only process n=2 and n=3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the loop ends far too soon. if `a == 3`, `a[j] == 0` and the loop ends. Change your main loop to:

```
for (j = 1; j < 50; j++) 
{
    k = 1;
    n = a[j];

    if (n != 0) 
        while (j + n * k <= 99) 
        {
            a[j + n * k] = 0;
            k++;
        }
}
```