# Why isn't there an array length function in C?

Tags: c, arrays

While there are [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415524/common-array-length-macro-for-c) ways to find the length of an array in C, the language doesn't provide one.

What was the reason for not including such a common operation in C or any of its revisions?

Comment: There is an operator (applied twice) which is better than a function. Why would you prefer a function over an operator? ??? You also don't use a function to add two numbers, do you?

Comment: It's just a pointer to a block of memory. In languages like java there is an extra level of indirection allowing support for .length attributes etc.

Comment: Arrays don't have a lot of visibility in C, so such a function would be of somewhat limited use.

Comment: @Adam: No, arrays are not pointers. Arrays are arrays.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: In C, there are no arrays, only pointers. What you think of as arrays is actually just syntactic sugar for pointers. A C compiler takes something like `x[y]` and changes it to `*(x + y)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I stand corrected. Is this true in both C and C++? I thought OP was about C, not C++...

Comment: @Swiss: you might like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/). Since you're there read the other sections too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the guiding philosophies of C's design is that all data types map directly to memory, and attempting to store metadata for array types such as length runs counter to that philosophy.

From an [article](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) by Dennis Ritchie describing the development of C, we find this:

> **Embryonic C**
> ...
> These semantics represented an easy transition from B, and I experimented with them for some months. Problems became evident when I tried to extend the type notation, especially to add structured (record) types. Structures, it seemed, should map in an intuitive way onto memory in the machine, but in a structure containing an array, there was no good place to stash the pointer containing the base of the array, nor any convenient way to arrange that it be initialized. For example, the directory entries of early Unix systems might be described in C as
>
> ```
>     struct {
>         int     inumber;
>         char    name[14];
>     };
> ```
>
> **I wanted the structure not merely to characterize an abstract object but also to describe a collection of bits that might be read from a directory.** Where could the compiler hide the pointer to name that the semantics demanded? Even if structures were thought of more abstractly, and the space for pointers could be hidden somehow, how could I handle the technical problem of properly initializing these pointers when allocating a complicated object, perhaps one that specified structures containing arrays containing structures to arbitrary depth?
>
> The solution constituted the crucial jump in the evolutionary chain between typeless BCPL and typed C. It eliminated the materialization of the pointer in storage, and instead caused the creation of the pointer when the array name is mentioned in an expression. The rule, which survives in today's C, is that values of array type are converted, when they appear in expressions, into pointers to the first of the objects making up the array.

Emphasis mine. Just replace the term "pointer" with "metadata" in the passage above, and I think we have the answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

Unless someone here happens to be on the C standard committee, you're unlikely to get an authoritative answer.  But two reasons I can think of:

1. In many (most?) situations, you don't have an array, you just have a pointer.
2. Storing metadata about the array increases the storage size, etc.  The general rule of C is that you don't pay for what you don't use.

Comment: Well, this is stackoverflow. You never know who might reply. :)

Answer (score 1):

C is not object-oriented, so it has no concept of methods that are attached to objects.  It was designed with speed and simplicity in mind, and the common idiom `sizeof (array) / sizeof(array[0])` is short and straightforward.

Comment: I wouldn't call `sizeof (array) / sizeof(array[0])` straightforward. In particular, I don't think it's obvious what's happening when `array[0]` is unallocated.

Comment: @hgpc: array elements are always allocated. But you can even "dereference" a NULL pointer with `sizeof`. The operator doesn't evaluate the argument: `struct tm *ptr = NULL; if (sizeof *ptr == sizeof (struct tm)) printf("OK\n");`

Comment: Are you saying that (size of a bunch of things) / (size of one thing) is not a straightforward calculation of the number of things?  Note, also, that `sizeof(thing)` calculates the size of `thing` but does not actually access it, so it's irrelevant whether `thing` has actually been allocated.  Have you read the documentation?

Comment: @Adam Liss No. (size of a bunch of things) / (size of one thing) is obvious. `sizeof(array[0])` isn't (even worse if you consider C++; see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4415646/143378). And I didn't say I don't understand it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is down to efficiency. C is a very efficient programing language.

Comment: Given that there's a way to find the length of an array anyway, why would making it "official" make C less inefficient?

Comment: @hgpc - It is efficient that the length is not stored. You can create an array of arbitrary size with `malloc`.

Comment: The efficient programming language makes people inefficient

Answer (score 0):

Array syntax in C is just a syntactic sugar for pointer arithmetic. If you want to have a real array with length and bounds checking, you can create a struct which contains an array pointer and its length and access it only through functions which check bounds.