# Doubts on char* list[] with return length C and C++

Tags: c, visual-c++

If I wrote it in the following way, I return the result as 1.  Don't understand why?  The expected answer is 5.

```
    int main()
    {
      const char* list_of_filename[] = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};

      printf("%d", countFiles(list_of_filename));

      return 0;
    }

    int countFiles(const char* list_of_filename[])
    {
      return sizeof(list_of_filename) / sizeof(list_of_filename[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` for an array only works in the scope where you declare the array.

```
  const char* list_of_filename[] = {"One","Two","Three","Four","Five"};
  printf("%d", sizeof(list_of_filenames) / sizeof(list_of_filenames[0]));
```

In C, you can not pass arrays.  So:

```
int countFiles(const char* list_of_filename[])
```

is exactly the same as:

```
int countFiles(const char **list_of_filename)
```

So you're comparing the sizes of two pointers.  The size of `const char *` and `const char **` are the same on your system.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415646/47773) (by Michael Burr, but originally from Chromium) provides a macro that does the array size calculation, and errors on some invalid constructs like this (but not this one)

Answer (score 2):

As a function argument,

```
const char* list_of_filename[]
```

actually means:

```
const char** list_of_filename.
```

Therefore what you're in fact calculating is:

```
sizeof(char**) / sizeof(char*)
```

`char**` and `char*` are both just pointers, and since all pointers *generally* have the same size (at least in this case, for you, these two do):

```
x / x
= 1
```

**EDIT:** When passing an array to a function in C, you'll generally either want to pass the size of the array or terminate your array with a specific value in order to be able to determine the length of it.

Answer (score 1):

From the C standard (`C11 6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators, para 3`):

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the
>   unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

In other words, when you pass that array to a function, it becomes a pointer to the first element of the array and its size is therefore the size of a pointer.

If you want to treat it as an array within the function, you need to explicitly pass in the size information with something like:

```
void printArray (int *arr, size_t sz) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        print ("%d ", arr[i]);
    puts ("");
}
:
int xyzzy[] = {3,1,3,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5,8,9};
printArray (xyzzy, sizeof (xyzzy) / sizeof (*xyzzy));
```

Comment: xyzzy?  You are in a maze of twisty little array indices, all alike.  :-)

Comment: @Adam, congrats on being the first to recognise the reference despite me having been using xyzzy and plugh for several months now. As a prize, you get a random upvoe to three of your answers, provided I can find three that are worthy :-)

Comment: What, with your bare hands?  Plugh!  (I guess we're both showing our age, huh?)

Comment: I just looked that up, that's one seriously old game.

Answer (score 0):

**C Arrays and Pointers are not the same!**

One of the first things that novice C programmers often hear is that "arrays are the same as pointers.". Unfortunately, this is a dangerous half-truth. The ANSI C Standard paragraph 6.5.4.2 recommends that you

> Note the distinction between the declarations:

```
extern int *x;
extern int y[];
```

> The first declares x to be a pointer to int; the second
>   declares y to be an array of int of unspecified size (an incomplete
>   type), the storage for which is defined elsewhere.

The standard doesn't go into the matter in any greater detail than that.

So when you try to get `sizeof` from array it returns size of the whole array in bytes (sum of objects' sizes), when you try to get `sizeof` of pointer - it returns size of pointer in bytes. Size of pointers it is always constant value on one platform. Generally it is 4 or 8 bytes.

Remember this :)