# Initialization of list of sets of integers in C++98

Tags: c++, list, set

this might seem trivial but I wasn't able to find it on the web so far, so

I want to initialize a list of sets of integers or a set of sets of integers, like this:

```
list< set<int> > lsi = {{}};
```

or maybe like this:

```
set< set<int> > ssi = {{5}, {6}, {7}};
```

**in C++98**. The reason for this is that I have  to submit it as an exercise in a submission system that does not accept C++11.

I have found out how to initialize a container in the old syntax from an array of integers, for example

```
int tmp[] = {1,2,3};
set<int> s (tmp, tmp + sizeof(tmp) / sizeof(tmp));
```

but not a `list< set<int> >`.

Comment: There's no nice way to do that (which is why C++11 introduced the new syntax), but there is a [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you Mike for your answer, but I can't even use C++11 so boost is not an option either.

Comment: You don't need C++11 to use the Boost library.

Comment: Why do you need `list< set<int> > lsi = {{}};` and not simply `list<set<int>> lsi;` in the first case? There is no need to value-initialize an empty container.

Comment: The submission system does not provide anything except the standard library.

Comment: @pantelis300: Quite conversely, Boost is what you _want_ to use in order to get access to features that eventually became part of C++11!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not possible without c+11 / boost.

That being said, the shortest way to initialize would probably be repeating `set`'s initialization (which you mentioned in your question):

```
int set1v[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int set2v[] = {11, 22, 33, 44};
int set3v[] = {15, 25, 35, 45};

set<int> setV[] = {
    set<int>(set1v, set1v + sizeof(set1v) / sizeof(set1v[0])),
    set<int>(set2v, set2v + sizeof(set2v) / sizeof(set2v[0])),
    set<int>(set3v, set3v + sizeof(set3v) / sizeof(set3v[0]))
};

set< set<int> > mySet(setV, setV + sizeof(setV) / sizeof(setV[0]));
```

---

Btw, Since you're checking arrays' sizes so many times I'd suggest you use a [count macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4415646/3374591):

```
#define COUNT_OF(x) ((sizeof(x)/sizeof(0[x])) / ((size_t)(!(sizeof(x) % sizeof(0[x])))))
```

It will look a little better:

```
#define END_OF(x) (x + COUNT_OF(x))

int set1v[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int set2v[] = {11, 22, 33, 44};
int set3v[] = {15, 25, 35, 45};

set<int> setV[] = {
    set<int>(set1v, END_OF(set1v)),
    set<int>(set2v, END_OF(set2v)),
    set<int>(set3v, END_OF(set3v))
};

set< set<int> > mySet(setV, END_OF(setV));
```

Comment: Let me guess, you created instances of the sets on the stack. This was how my first solution looked too. :)

Comment: Nope, 
set<int> setV[] = { set1v, set2v, set3v };
so close yet so far :-)

Comment: nice, there is always room for improvement ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you some approach I have used to initialize static STL storages, but the syntax becomes somewhat obscure for this case:

```
template <typename Type>
struct SetInit : public std::set<Type> {
    SetInit<Type>& operator()(const Type& data) {
        this->insert(data);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main () {
    std::set<std::set<int> > test_set = SetInit<std::set<int> >() // Call ctor
        (SetInit<int>()(1)(2)(3))(SetInit<int>()(4)(5)(6)); // Each element in () is inserted in the set
    return 0;
}
```

The basic idea is to use an operator() to include elements in the storage. The advantage of this idea is that it can be used to initialize `static` lists and sets because the expressions can be evaluated at compile time.