# C++ unsigned char array length

Tags: c++, linux, uart

I have in my C++ program unsigned char array of hex values:

```
unsigned char buff[] = {0x03, 0x35, 0x6B};
```

And I would like to calculate the size of this array so that I can send it on UART port linux using this function:

```
if ((count = write(file,buff,length))<0)
{
    perror("FAIL to write on exit\n"); 
}
```

as I can see the length is int number, and buff is an array which can change size during program execution.
can anyone help me how to write it. Thanks

Comment: `buff` can't change it's size during program execution. It's initialized with a literal and will have a length of 3 always

Comment: The *values*  aren't hexadecimal, you 've only written them in hexadecimal notation. `{3, 53, 107}` is exactly equivalent, and so is `{03, 065, 0153}`.

Comment: @Story Teller This is only an example, buff can have different numbers of values stored in him.

Comment: So it's a bare pointer? `unsigned char *buff`?

Comment: No, it is array. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an array:

```
size_t size = sizeof array;
```

with your example that give:

```
ssize_t count = write(file, buff, sizeof buff);
if (count < 0 || (size_t)count != sizeof buff) {
  perror("FAIL to write on exit\n");
}
```

Note: I use C semantic because write is from lib C.

---

In C++, you can use template to be sure that you use `sizeof` with an array.

```
template<typename T, size_t s>
size_t array_sizeof(T (&array)[s]) {
    return sizeof array;
}
```

with your example that give:

```
ssize_t count = write(file, buff, array_sizeof(buff));
if (count < 0 || static_cast<size_t>(count) != array_sizeof(buff)) {
  perror("FAIL to write on exit\n");
}
```

Comment: @jww I clearly say "with an array". And of course with pointer there is no point to do that! No that doesn't "fail" with pointer. This lead to a different result. With different purpose. I just answer with the **context** of the question.

Answer (score 5):

As one of the options to get the **number of elements** you can use such template:

```
template<typename T, size_t s>
size_t arrSize(T(&)[s])
{
    return s;
}
```

And afterwards call:

```
auto length = arrSize(buff);
```

This could be used across the code for various array types.

In case by array size you mean its **total byte size** you can just use the `sizeof(buff)`. Or as others suggested you can use `std::array`, `std::vector` or any other container instead and write a helper like this:

```
template<typename T>
size_t byteSize(const T& data)
{
    typename T::value_type type;
    return data.size() * sizeof(type);
}
```

Then to acquire the actual byte size of the data you can simply call:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buff{0x03, 0x35, 0x6B};
auto bSize = byteSize(buff);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note: this is better than the `sizeof array / sizeof *array` method, as it will always fail to compile if you call it with something that has an operator `*` but is not an array. The other method will compile and silently give wrong results.

Comment: @Stargateur Thanks for the note, fixed that

Answer (score 2):

If you are using C++11 you might think of switching to

```
#include <array>
std::array<char, 3> buff{ {0x03, 0x35, 0x6B} };
```

That offers an interface like `std::vector` (including `size` & `data`) for fixed arrays. 
Using `array` might prevent some usual errors and offer some functionality covered by `<algorithm>`.

The call to `write` will then be:

```
write(file,buff.data(),buf.size())
```

Comment: Great advice, but do note that `<algorithm>` works with C-style arrays too.

Comment: doesn't anwser the OP, this give the number of elem the op want the size in bytes.

Comment: size in byte and size is equal in case of char. Using an other type you can use multiplication with size_type

Answer (score 0):

> And I would like to calculate the size of this array so that I can send it on UART port linux using this function...

You need a `COUNTOF` macro or function. They can be tricky to get right in all cases. For example, the accepted answer shown below will silently fail when working with pointers:

```
size_t size = sizeof array;
size_t number_element = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
```

Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 has a built-in macro or template class called `_countof`. It handles all cases properly. Also see the [_countof Macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175773.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

On non-Microsoft systems, I believe you can use something like the following. It will handle pointers properly (from [making COUNTOF suck less](http://blog.natekohl.net/making-countof-suck-less/)):

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper( T (&arr)[N] ))[N];
#define COUNTOF(arr) ( sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(arr)) )

void foo(int primes[]) {
   // compiler error: primes is not an array
   std::cout << COUNTOF(primes) << std::endl;
}
```

Another good reference is [Better array 'countof' implementation with C++ 11](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0708.html). It discusses the ways to do things incorrectly, and how to do things correctly under different compilers, like Clang, ICC, GCC and MSVC. It include the Visual Studio trick.

---

> buff is an array which can change size during program execution

As long as you have the data at compile time, the `countof` macro or function should work. If you are building data on the fly, then it probably won't work.

---

This is closely related: [Common array length macro for C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4415524/608639). It may even be a duplicate.

Comment: doesn't anwser the OP, this give the number of elem the op want the size in bytes.