# Standard macro to calculate the number of elements in an array

Tags: c

Is there something like this available in the C standard library:

```
#define sizeofarr(a)    ( sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) )
```

Comment: if you have an array where the size is known at compile time, you can do it, but otherwise no

Comment: @bruceg `( sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) )` works for VLAs too - array who size is not known at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not such a thing!

For better Macro definition check this link directly:

[is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array/1598827#1598827)

or [common-array-length-macro-for-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415524/common-array-length-macro-for-c)

Answer (score 2):

No. There is not something like that available in the C standard library.