# What's the purpose of dummy addition in this "number of elements" macro?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, visual-c++, macros

Visual C++ 10 is shipped with stdlib.h that among other things contains this gem:

```
template <typename _CountofType, size_t _SizeOfArray>
char (*__countof_helper(UNALIGNED _CountofType (&_Array)[_SizeOfArray]))[_SizeOfArray];

#define _countof(_Array) (sizeof(*__countof_helper(_Array)) + 0)
```

which uses [a clever template trick to deduce array size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7966964/57428) and *prevent pointers from being passed into `__countof`*.

What's the purpose of `+ 0` in the macro definition? What problem does it solve?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is preventing it to be usable in template specializations. That's a limitation though.

Comment: Of course, if VS2010 supported `constexpr` then it would be: `template <typename T, size_t N> constexpr size_t size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Quoting STL from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160406225537/https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/567789-template-countof-confusion-question/619852a9a6c74beb8ba69e110013279c)

> I made this change; I don't usually hack the CRT, but this one was
>   trivial.  The + 0 silences a spurious "warning C6260: sizeof * sizeof
>   is usually wrong. Did you intend to use a character count or a byte
>   count?" from /analyze when someone writes _countof(arr) * sizeof(T).

Answer (score 2):

> What's the purpose of + 0 in the macro definition? What problem does
>   it solve?

I don't feel it solves any problem. It might be used to silence some warning as mentioned in another answer.

On the important note, following is another way of finding the array size at compile time (personally I find it more readable):

```
template<unsigned int SIZE>
struct __Array { char a[SIZE]; }

template<typename T, unsigned int SIZE>
__Array<SIZE> __countof_helper(const T (&)[SIZE]);

#define _countof(_Array) (sizeof(__countof_helper(_Array)))
```

[P.S.: Consider this as a comment]

Comment: Bad identifier names... Bad identifier names!

Comment: @Xeo, assumed that this is used for library code (OP), which already contains `__` and `_` followed by caps. Copied from the source in the question.

Comment: @iammilind: I find this more readable too, however the good thing about the VS way is that it avoids introducing a spurious `struct`.

Comment: @MatthieuM., ok. And I can recall that, I [learned this from you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018843/macro-definition-array-size/8021113#8021113) only. :)