# C++: sizeof for array length

Tags: c++, macros

Let's say I have a macro called `LengthOf(array)`:

```
sizeof array / sizeof array[0]
```

When I make a new array of size 23, shouldn't I get 23 back for `LengthOf`?

```
WCHAR* str = new WCHAR[23];
str[22] = '\0';
size_t len = LengthOf(str); // len == 4
```

Why does `len == 4`?

**UPDATE**: I made a typo, it's a `WCHAR*`, not a `WCHAR**`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sizeof( a pointer pointing to an array )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array) (There might be a better match; this was the best I could find with a quick search).

Comment: You probably want a `std::vector<std::wstring> >` or something. This is C++, not C.

Answer (score 12):

Because `str` here is a pointer to a pointer, not an array.

This is one of the fine differences between pointers and arrays: in this case, your *pointer* is on the stack, pointing to the array of 23 characters that has been allocated elsewhere (presumably the heap).

Answer (score 11):

```
WCHAR** str = new WCHAR[23];
```

First of all, this shouldn't even compile -- it tries to assign a `pointer to WCHAR` to a `pointer to pointer to WCHAR`. The compiler should reject the code based on this mismatch.

Second, one of the known shortcomings of the `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` macro is that it can and will fail completely when applied to a pointer instead of a real array. In C++, you can use a template to get code like this rejected:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, size_t N>
size_t size(T (&x)[N]) { 
    return N;
}

int main() { 
    int a[4];
    int *b;

    b = ::new int[20];

    std::cout << size(a);      // compiles and prints '4'
//    std::cout << size(b);    // uncomment this, and the code won't compile.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the macro fails to work properly if a pointer is passed to it instead of an actual array.  Unfortunately, because pointers and arrays evaluate similarly in most expressions, the compiler isn't able to let you know there's a problem unless you make you macro somewhat more complex.

For a C++ version of the macro that's typesafe (will generate an error if you pass a pointer rather than an array type), see:

- [Compile time sizeof_array without using a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500363/compile-time-sizeofarray-without-using-a-macro/1500917#1500917)

It wouldn't exactly 'fix' your problem, but it would let you know that you're doing something wrong.

For a macro that works in C and is somewhat safer (many pointers will diagnose as an error, but some will pass through without error - including yours, unfortunately):

- [Is there a standard function in C that would return the length of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598773/is-there-a-standard-function-in-c-that-would-return-the-length-of-an-array/1598827#1598827)

Of course, using the power of `#ifdef __cplusplus` you can have both in a general purpose header and have the compiler select the safer one for C++ builds and the C-compatible one when C++ isn't in effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `sizeof` operator checks the size of it's argument. The argument passed in your sample code is `WCHAR*`. So, the sizeof(WCHAR*) is 4. If you had an array, such as `WCHAR foo[23]`, and took `sizeof(foo)`, the type passed is `WCHAR[23]`, essentially, and would yield `sizeof(WCHAR) * 23`.  Effectively at compile type `WCHAR*` and `WCHAR[23]` are different types, and while you and I can see that the result of `new WCHAR[23]` is functionally equivalent to `WCHAR[23]`, in actuality, the return type is `WCHAR*`, with absolutely no size information.

As a corellary, since `sizeof(new WCHAR[23])` equals 4 on your platform, you're obviously dealing with an architecture where a pointer is 4 bytes. If you built this on an x64 platform, you'd find that `sizeof(new WCHAR[23])` will return 8.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
WCHAR* str = new WCHAR[23];
```

if 23 is meant to be a static value, (not variable in the entire life of your program) it's better **use #define or const than just hardcoding** 23.

```
#define STR_LENGTH 23
WCHAR* str = new WCHAR[STR_LENGTH];
size_t len = (size_t) STR_LENGTH;
```

or C++ version

```
const int STR_LENGTH = 23;
WCHAR* str = new WCHAR[STR_LENGTH];
size_t len = static_cast<size_t>(STR_LENGTH);
```