# sizeof char* array in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sizeof

There are plenty of similar inquires, but in my case I don't understand what isn't working:

```
int mysize = 0;
mysize = sizeof(samplestring) / sizeof(*samplestring);
std::cout << mysize << '\n' << samplestring;
```

This outputs:

```
4

Press 'q' to quit.
```

How is it possible? 4 definitely isn't the size of this string. I even tried the following, with the same result:

`mysize = sizeof(samplestring) / sizeof(samplestring[0]);`

EDIT: Ok, this is the declaration:

```
char *samplestring = "Start.";
```

I'm on C++, but I need to use functions that only accept char *. Later in the code I assign new strings to that variable, like:

```
samplestring = "Press 'r' for red text.";
```

Yes, the compiler gives me warnings, but I have no idea how can I use different strings if I can't overwrite them...

Comment: how is `samplestring` declared?

Comment: where is the definition of `samplestring` ?

Comment: You managed to leave out the most important piece of info!

Comment: string is a char array isnt it? *p gives the first element if it is an array. You need a wrapper class to get size more correctly. I think your array is qwe+NULL

Comment: In C++, char * is not the same as std:string, nor is it same as Java's String or python strings. If you want to understand char *, please start with K&R C - literally read K&R book. Otherwise, stay with std::string - it may keep you safe for a while.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: sizeof for array length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2993646/c-sizeof-for-array-length)

Comment: Solved my problem by converting to C++ string: std::string cppstring(samplestring);
stringlength = cppstring.size();

Comment: I'm reiterating previous comments, but really guy @Abalieno? Not including the definition of sampleString? Can this question be archived/removed so that it doesn't appear as a possible solution for people with similar questions as myself just to find a fractured question body? Wasteful of time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`4` isn't the size of the string, because `samplestring` isn't a string. It's a `char*`, whose size is (on your platform) 4, divided by 1 (size of `char`) is, correctly, 4.

In C++, you'd use `std::string` and the `length()` method.

In C, you'd use `strlen` which takes as parameter a NULL-terminated char pointer.

Comment: Is there a good reference (e.g. web page) where I can find out the size of char* on various platforms?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways of making a string constant, and your technique only works on the first one. The first one makes an array of characters which you can get the size of at compile time, and the other creates a *pointer* to an array of characters.

```
char samplestring[] = "hello";
char * samplestring = "hello";
```

Trying to take the size of the second case the way you're doing it just gives you the size of a pointer. On a 32-bit build the size of a pointer is 4 characters, i.e. a pointer takes the same amount of memory as 4 characters.

The following will *always* give the correct length for a properly null-terminated string, but it's slower.

```
mysize = strlen(samplestring);
```

Comment: Note (for the op): the first would decay to a pointer if passed to a function, so the `sizeof` would give the result you expect only in the same context.

Comment: strlen is good.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `sizeof(samplestring[0])` is the same as `sizeof(*samplestring)`, they're both returning the size of the first element of the `samplestring` array. And, assuming `samplestring` is an array of chars, `sizeof(char)` is defined to be 1.

You haven't shown how `samplestring` is declared. It could be one of the following:

```
char const *samplestring = "Hello, World!";
```

or

```
char *samplestring = malloc( ... );
```

or

```
char samplestring[10];
```

In the first 2 cases the type of `samplestring` is `char *`, so `sizeof(samplestring)` returns `sizeof(char *)`, which, on your platform is 4.

In the third case, the type of `samplestring` is `char[10]` (array of 10 chars), but if you call a function that takes a `char *` as its parameter, the char array will *decay* to a pointer pointing to the first element of the array. In this case, trying to print `sizeof` within the function will still result in the size of a pointer being printed.

If you want the size of the original array to be printed from within the function, then the function parameter needs to be a pointer to the original array type (and the type includes size of the original array).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo( char (*arr)[42] )
{
  printf( "%u", (unsigned)sizeof(*arr) );
}

int main()
{
  char arr[42];
  foo( &arr );

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42
```

This fixes the size of the array that can be passed to the function and is not desirable in a lot of cases. The only other solution is to keep track of the array yourself (or use `strlen` if you have a NULL terminated string).

Answer (score 3):

It looks as though you have a pointer, not an array. Arrays are converted to pointers when the program requires it, so you'd get:

```
size_t size(char * p) { // p is a pointer
    return sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p); // size of pointer
}

size_t size(char p[]) { // p is also a pointer        
    return sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p); // size of pointer
}
```

although, since `sizeof (char) == 1`, the division is redundant here; if the pointer were to a larger type, then you'd get a differently unexpected result.

In C++ (but obviously not C), you can deduce the size of an array as a template parameter:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;  // size of array
}
```

or you can use classes such as `std::vector` and `std::string` to keep track of the size.

In C, you can use `strlen` to find the length of a zero-terminated string, but in most cases you'll need to keep track of array sizes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you are asking the size of a pointer on a char. So I guess you're using a 32bit system.

If you're using C++, use std::string :

```
std::string samplestring("Hello world");
std::cout << samplestring.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: But I'm forced to do some back and forth, so how can I put a char * into a proper c++ string, do my operations, then send it back to a char * ?

Comment: std::string samplestring(your_c_string); samplestring.c_str();

Answer (score 0):

The sizeof of an element returns the size of the memory allocated for that object.
In your example the string is probably declared somewhere as

```
samplestring[4]
```

In which case the size of the memory is 4.
The method you probably want in your application is

```
strlen(samplestring);
```

Which returns the size of the null terminated string (without the termination)