# sizeof Calloc producing wrong output

Tags: arrays, c, memory, calloc

I created a calloc object :

```
char* i2s_read_buff = (char*) calloc(1024*16, sizeof(char));
```

What I understood from the definition of calloc is that it will create array of 1024*16 elements and each element will be 1 byte. So it should be a `1024*16/8 = 2048` bytes array.

But

```
sizeof(i2s_read_buff)
```

produces output `4`. I was expecting `2048` as output.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: You are getting the size of char * which is different fron the memory allocation done at the pointer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281686/determine-size-of-dynamically-allocated-memory-in-c

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL isnt sizeof(char) is 1 always?

Comment: sizeof(char *) is different from sizeof(char): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353973/sizeof-char-array-in-c-c

Comment: I do not get the `/8` part of your calculation. It seems that you think the size of a `char` is one eigth of a byte.