# does Qt implement _countof or equivalent?

Tags: qt

I really like using the _countof() macro in VS and I'm wondering if there is an OS-generic implementation of this in Qt.

For those unaware, _countof() gives you the number of elements in the array. so,

wchar_t buf[256];

_countof(buf) => 256 (characters)
sizeof(buf) => 512  (bytes)

It's very nice for use with, say, unicode strings, where it gives you character count.

I'm hoping Qt has a generic version.

Comment: If you are already using Qt, you should be using QString :)

Comment: The mistake is to use arrays :) Use QString, QByteArray, QVector/std::vector etc.

Comment: The following question has the answer you want to provide a generic and safe macro for all OSes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500363/compile-time-sizeof-array-without-using-a-macro/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_countof` is probably defined like this:

```
#define _countof(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
```

You can use a definition like this with any compiler and OS.

If there is no such macro provided by Qt you can simply define a custom one yourself in one of your header files.

Comment: I just added a macro conditionally.  the MS version apparently does something a bit more complete than this with templates, to ensure the argument is an array-type, but this works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

[sth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56338/sth)'s code will work fine, but won't detect when you're trying to get the size of a pointer rather than an array. The MS solution does this (as [danielweberdlc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291193/danielweberdlc) says), but it's possible to have this as a standard solution for C++:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
  #define ARRAYLENGTH(x) _countof(x)
#else // !Q_OS_WIN
  template< typename T, std::size_t N > 
  inline std::size_t ARRAYLENGTH(T(&)[N]) { return N; }
#endif // !Q_OS_WIN
```

A more detailed description of this solution is given [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/arrays/sizeof-array/).