# pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11

why does the pointer array "equivalence" not work in the following case?

```
void foo(int** x) {
  cout << x[0][1];
}

int main( ) {
  int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{2,3}};
  foo(a);  
}
```

thank you

Comment: What doesn't work? what error message are you getting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C, are arrays pointers or used as pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers)

Comment: The pointer array "equivalence"

Comment: @ildjam, no its not duplicate, there the 1D case is discussed for which the pointer array "equivalence" works

Comment: @user695652: ...Because there's no such thing as "pointer array equivalence" and there never was. In fact, your example is a direct proof of that.

Comment: @user695652 : The accepted answer there also answers your question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The memory model of int** and int[2][2] is different.
`int a[2][2]` is stored in memory as:

```
&a     : a[0][0]
&a + 4 : a[0][1]
&a + 8 : a[1][0]
&a + 12: a[1][1]
```

`int** x`:

```
&x       : addr1
&x + 4   : addr2
addr1    : x[0][0]
addr1 + 4: x[0][1]
addr2    : x[1][0]
addr2 + 4: x[1][1]
```

while `addr1` and `addr2` are just addresses in memory.
You just can't convert one to the other.

Comment: `&x` would be of type `int***` ... did you mean `*x` or `x[INDEX]`, where `x` is dereferenced to give the `int*` it's pointing to (which in this case is pointing to an array of type `int`)?

Comment: It's actually x instead of &x as it's the address of the 2 other addresses.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because only the first level of the multidimensional array decays to a pointer. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

void foo(int (*x)[2]) {
  cout << x[0][1];
}

int main( ) {
  int a[2][2] = {{1,2},{2,3}};
  foo(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because the type is not int **. this right for foo function

foo(int *[2]);

type of pointer a is not int ** , exactly int* [2]..