# Loop asking user for input into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

You all have helped me so much in the past, I am coming back for more help!

I am working on another C++ assignment for school. I have to collect 20 numbers between 10 and 100 from the user and compare them all and print out the ones that are not duplicates.

The part I am stuck on is trying to get the user input to loop until I have all 20 numbers. What I have makes sense to me, but it apparently is not working. Sorry for the ridiculous comments, I have to comment everything for class.

Any light you can shed on my goof up would be amazing! Thank you so much!

```
int FindDuplicates[20]; // my little array
int UserInput; // the number from the user to compare
int count; // the number of numbers entered

for(count=0; count<FindDuplicates; count++;) // what I am trying to do is have count start at 0. as long as it is less than the max array, add 1 to the count
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 10 and 100: "; // print out what I would like
    cin >> UserInput; // get the number from the user
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is how to enter 20 valid numbers, is it?
I think the do while loop will help you.

```
int FindDuplicates[20]; // my little array
int UserInput; // the number from the user to compare
int count = 0; // the number of numbers entered

do
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 10 and 100: "; // print out what I would like
    cin >> UserInput; // get the number from the user

    if (UserInput >= 10 && UserInput <= 100)
    count++;
} while (count < 20);
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems so easy now that I see it! All I had to add was the line adding the UserInput into the array in the slot marked by count!

Answer (score 3):

```
for( int count = 0; count < 20; count++ )
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 10 and 100: ";
    cin >> userInput;

    FindDuplicates[ count ] = userInput;
}
```

You can also check for valid input with:

```
while( UserInput < 10 || UserInput > 100 )
{
    cout << "Please enter a number between 10 and 100: ";
    cin >> UserInput;
}
```

If you do that just make sure you have initialized UserInput to something. So:

```
int FindDuplicates[ 20 ];
int UserInput = 0;
int count = 0;

//count has already been defined, so no need to do it again
for( ; count < 20; count++ )
{
    //Keep asking until valid input is given
    while( UserInput < 10 || UserInput > 100 )
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 10 and 100: ";
        cin >> userInput;
    }

    //Add userInput into the array
    FindDuplicates[ count ] = UserInput;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FindDuplicates` will give you the pointer pointed to the array (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers/4608421#4608421)), not the size. You should use

`for(count=0; count<20; count++;)`

instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error on the line below, check how for statements work. There's also a problem with the `<FindDuplicates`. Make sure you understand what that variable means.

`for(count=0; count<FindDuplicates; count++;)`