# What Is The Difference Between char**x and char*x[]

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C, are arrays pointers or used as pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers)

In C++, the default main function can have arguments like char* argv[]. What is the its difference from char** and char* argv[100] ?

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in function parameters. In other situations, the first declares a pointer, the second declares an array.

Comment: There is a difference. In `char* [100]` you have some more information.

Comment: @J.N. Not in function parameters. In function parameters, if the rightmost type is an array, the size is ignored.

Comment: @J.N. There's no difference between the two declarations when they appear in function declaration.

Comment: Indeed, I was wrong, though it would be useful to disambiguate. The difference only applies for array references.

Answer (score 1):

`char**` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

The second `char *argv[100]` is an array of pointers to a char.

But when you pass an array to functions they **decay** to a pointer.

Comment: Decay?  like zombies decay and become decrepit and begin losing body parts?

Comment: Ha ha this isn't The Walking Dead :) 
That is just the terminology used.

Comment: Well, if you use C-arrays and `char*` in C++, you are mentally a zombie.

Comment: @RichardChambers See [this explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4607149/478288).

Comment: @daknøk, personally I think throwing a bit of C into C++ adds flavor and vitamins with a touch of job security as well!  And what is this bit about having to do a head shot to kill a zombie if they have no brains?

Comment: I’d never hire a C++ programmer that uses C-arrays instead of `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 1):

`char** argv`:  To elicit the same behavior as char* argv[100] you must dynamically allocate space to store char pointers. For example: `(*argv) = new char[100];`

Double pointers are a very flexible datatype unique to C++ which can grant insane speed and insane bugs. Generally if you know the size of your array, its best to avoid dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: They are not unique to C++ ;). You can have them in C and Pascal for instance.

Comment: I think this was a joke post and not meant to be taken seriously.

Comment: Argh I think it's time to go to bed, I stopped at the first part of the sentence.

Comment: <laughter>  More coffee!!  Or Red Bull.